# Apply function to all elements of collection through LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have recently started off with LINQ and its amazing. I was wondering if LINQ would allow me to apply a function - any function - to all the elements of a collection, without using foreach. Something like python lambda functions.

For example if I have a int list, Can I add a constant to every element using LINQ

If i have a DB table, can i set a field for all records using LINQ.

I am using C#

Answer (score 165, accepted):

A common way to approach this is to add your own `ForEach` generic method on `IEnumerable<T>`. Here's the one we've got in [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/):

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    source.ThrowIfNull("source");
    action.ThrowIfNull("action");
    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        action(element);
    }
}
```

(Where `ThrowIfNull` is an extension method on any reference type, which does the obvious thing.)

It'll be interesting to see if this is part of .NET 4.0. It goes against the functional style of LINQ, but there's no doubt that a lot of people find it useful.

Once you've got that, you can write things like:

```
people.Where(person => person.Age < 21)
      .ForEach(person => person.EjectFromBar());
```

Comment: I never really understood the urge people have to do that. A foreach loop is more readable to my eyes; having a separation between the "functional" part that gets the data and the "action" part that operates on it helps clarify the structure of algorithms.

Comment: Yes, I generally prefer a foreach loop myself. On the other hand, if you've already been presented with a delegate to apply to each element, I'm not sure it's much more readable to call that delegate in an explicit foreach loop. I wouldn't use this often, but just occasionally it seems like a nice solution.

Comment: @Lodewijk: In what way is using a method which *has* to have side-effects in order to be any use functional? The `Where` part is functional... the `ForEach` part not so much, IMO.

Comment: Not in the functional-ishness part. Just in syntax.

Comment: @Lodewijk: Right, and that's where I question whether you're really getting any benefit. Why have code which *looks* somewhat functional, but violates the normal aims of functional programming? What's the benefit of that over a `foreach` loop? It feels like neither one thing nor the other to me.

Comment: It's definitely terrible to do an in-place change instead of returning the new type. That's going to confuse the hell out of a ton of programmers. The benefit is reduced to not having to nest foreaches or otherwise write ugly code. Oneliners can be very readable.

Comment: @Lodewijk Were your intentions to mean _declarative_?

Comment: @Alex, probably not. What do you mean? These "functional-ish" functions are ways to extend the control-flow, "map" specifically gets a lot of love. It makes it easy to take a collection and apply a function to everything in it. Having "map" instead of a 4 line foreach is good because it shows what it does less ambiguously (think zero-or-one-indexing-headaches), and briefer.

Having map return a new collection instead of doing inline-changes is more standard and more versatile. This "ForEach" isn't a map function though, and has less advantage over regular foreach loops.

Comment: @Lodewijk Well, the fundamental thing about declarative programming is that it is supposed to express _what_ to do, instead of _how_ to do it. It sounded like this was what you where after, being "less ambigious", "breifer" and "not the functional-ishness, just the syntax". Just like linq in general - a more declarative way to express complex logical operations.

Comment: how is this different to something like the select() linq method?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: `Select` is a projection: 1) it's lazily evaluated; just calling it won't do anything. 2) `Select` produces a result - `ForEach` doesn't.

Comment: @mquander I have a practical use case. I need to inject some logging between a pipeline of linq statements

Comment: @Martin: ForEach won't help you there - but a Select delegate that logs then returns it's input, or a Where delegate that logs then returns true would both work...

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks. I realized once I tried it didn't work. I found another way entirely for this problem, but next time I will consider the Select(...) way. It feels a bit "naughty" to introduce a side effect in Select, though. But I'll live.

Comment: I know this is an old question. I find the forEach very useful in RxJS, it feels like an omission in Linq currently, and I don't think it will confuse people as the purpose of a forEach lambda is to modify the items or do something specific with them, especially useful when dealing with EF entities where you definitely do not want new types. Our RxJs code is very legible and compact. Thank you @JonSkeet for this answer. We won't use all the time, but there are times where it will save quite a bit of foreach boiler plate.

Answer (score 106):

The idiomatic way to do this with LINQ is to process the collection and return a new collection mapped in the fashion you want.  For example, to add a constant to every element, you'd want something like

```
var newNumbers = oldNumbers.Select(i => i + 8);
```

Doing this in a functional way instead of mutating the state of your existing collection frequently helps you separate distinct operations in a way that's both easier to read and easier for the compiler to reason about.

If you're in a situation where you actually want to apply an action to every element of a collection (an action with side effects that are unrelated to the actual contents of the collection) that's not really what LINQ is best suited for, although you could fake it with `Select` (or write your own `IEnumerable` extension method, as many people have.)  It's probably best to stick with a `foreach` loop in that case.

Comment: Not to mention mutating a collection while iterating over it is dangerous, to impossible, depending on the language.

Comment: In C#, mutating the elements of the collection is fair game, but adding to or removing from the collection may either fail or yield unwanted results.

Comment: using the Select method only really helps with certain types, like int. What if you wanted to set the property of the objects in your list to a certain value? wouldn't it be simpler and more scalable to use .ForEach()?

Comment: If you already knew the new value, then typically (in the spirit of LINQ) you would tend to make a new list with the appropriate values in it, instead of changing the old one.  Of course, if you do have a list and you really want to change that particular list -- maybe it's databound to something -- then .ForEach() is fine, too.

Comment: LINQ defer execution might be a problem with `Select` if you don't iterate later on the result.

Comment: @Soviut `ForEach` doesn't mutate the collection. It may - and is often used to - edit the elements in the collection. Personally, I return the edited collection as a result, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: @andy Select method works for your use case as well (setting property of object to certain value). Example. `myItems.Select(item => { item.myProperty = someValue(); return item; } );`

Answer (score 51):

You could also consider going parallel, especially if you don't care about the sequence and more about getting something done for each item:

```
SomeIEnumerable<T>.AsParallel().ForAll( Action<T> / Delegate / Lambda )
```

For example:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
numbers.AsParallel().ForAll( Console.WriteLine );
```

HTH.

Comment: Please be careful of AsParallel().ForAll() as it causes unpredictive result. For example I have a button to execute this code when clicked: myEnumerable.AsParallel().ForAll(i as string => otherDictionary.Add(i, 0)) . It will add null as a key to otherDictionary. I had to rewrote to use foreach loop. Weird.

Comment: @YukiSakura Not really AsParallel().ForAll()'s fault - The bits that are dangerous is using shared stated between multiple threads and then that the cast of "i as string" is the possible cause passing in a null key. Care to share a more complete sample of your code for feedback on how to improve?

Answer (score 44):

haha, man, I just asked this question a few hours ago (kind of)...try this:

example:

```
someIntList.ForEach(i=>i+5);
```

`ForEach()` is one of the built in .NET methods

This will modify the list, as opposed to returning a new one.

Comment: Note that this only works on actual List<T> collections, unless you've defined your own ForEach method to do it.

Comment: I believe mquander was referring to the fact that ForEach is not defined on IEnumerable<T>, just List<T>

Comment: Yes, it won't work in most cases, because usually you will get an IEnumerable from your link query

Comment: I find most of the time adding `.ToList().ForEach(...)` is all I need.

Comment: Why this gives me : error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 14):

Or you can hack it up.

```
Items.All(p => { p.IsAwesome = true; return true; });
```

Comment: This is hacking "All" to turn it into "ForEach".  I have a bad feeling that this will mislead some newbie into thinking that "All" means "Execute on all elements".

Comment: Interesting. Does this actually edit the underlying collection? Are the objects returned copies?

Comment: @Zimano It does edit the underlying collection but does not return copies.

Answer (score 6):

For collections that do not support `ForEach` you can use static `ForEach` method in `Parallel` class:

```
var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 };
Parallel.ForEach(_your_collection_, options, x => x._Your_Method_());
```

Comment: this is really unintuitive.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```
var foo = (from fooItems in context.footable select fooItems.fooID + 1);
```

Returns a list of id's +1, you can do the same with using a function to whatever you have in the select clause.

Update: As suggested from Jon Skeet this is a better version of the snippet of code I just posted:

```
var foo = context.footable.Select(foo => foo.fooID + 1);
```

Comment: I'd suggest that in cases where you just need to do a simple projection, query expressions are over the top. I'd use "var foo = context.footable.Select(foo => foo.fooID + 1);"

Answer (score -1):

I found some way to perform in on dictionary contain my custom class methods

```
foreach (var item in this.Values.Where(p => p.IsActive == false))
            item.Refresh();
```

Where 'this' derived from : Dictionary<string, MyCustomClass>

```
class MyCustomClass 
{
   public void Refresh(){}
}
```