# Why does List<T>.ForEach() implement a for loop?

Tags: c#, .net, list, foreach

I don't understand why the `List<T>.ForEach()` extension method implements a `for` loop under the hood.  This opens up the possibility of the collection being modified.  A normal `foreach` will throw an exception in this case so surely `ForEach()` should react the same way?

If you MUST mutate a collection for whatever reason, then surely you should be manually iterating through the collection in a `for` loop?

There seems to be a bit of a semantic contradiction here between `foreach` and `List<T>.ForEach()`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: "This opens up the possibility of the collection being modified." [Exactly why it is now gone from .NET for Metro-style apps.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299458/is-the-listt-foreach-extension-method-gone/10299492#10299492) Ho hum.

Comment: Eric Lippert's (disapproving) [comments on `.ForEach`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) are always worth a read in this context.

Comment: by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299458/is-the-listt-foreach-extension-method-gone

Comment: @user287107: That's what I linked to not very long ago.

Comment: ... well thats what you get if you mutate data - sorry LINQ has deep FP roots and there is a reason why immutable data and referential transparency are *encouraged* in FP ... if you don't like the implementation then make your own - or better embrace immutable data!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only a member of the BCL team can tell us for sure, but it was probably just an oversight that `List<T>.ForEach` lets you modify the list.

First, David B's answer doesn't make sense to me. It's `List<T>`, not C#, that checks if you modify the list within a `foreach` loop and throws an `InvalidOperationException` if you do. It has nothing to do with the language you're using.

Second, there's this warning in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx):

> Modifying the underlying collection in the body of the Action<T> delegate is not supported and causes undefined behavior.

I find it unlikely that the BCL team wanted such a simple method like `ForEach` to have undefined behavior.

Third, as of .NET 4.5, `List<T>.ForEach` *will* throw an `InvalidOperationException` if the delegate modifies the list. If a program depends on the old behavior, [it will stop working](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx#core) when it's recompiled to target .NET 4.5. The fact that Microsoft is willing to accept this breaking change strongly suggests that the original behavior was unintended and should not be relied upon.

For reference, here's how `List<T>.ForEach` is implemented in .NET 4.0, straight from the reference source:

```
public void ForEach(Action<T> action) {
    if( action == null) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < _size; i++) {
        action(_items[i]);
    }
}
```

And here's how it's been changed in .NET 4.5:

```
public void ForEach(Action<T> action) {
    if( action == null) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    int version = _version;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < _size; i++) {
        if (version != _version && BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5) {
            break;
        }
        action(_items[i]);
    }

    if (version != _version && BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
}
```

Comment: @nawfal: Probably not. The cost of checking `if (version != _version)` is unlikely to be measurable.

Comment: Actually, it's documented to throw the exception not only if the list is modified but even if "an element in the calling collection is modified". That's crazy. Why deliberately break a benign behavior?

Answer (score 5):

Because [List.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) following the definition from MSDN:

> Performs the specified action on each element of the List.

That means that `Action` executed over the element, can potentially change element, *or collection itself*. In this case, there is no other way (if not creating costy clone collection, *if* it's possible) to afford this, then using a simple `for`.

If you change the collection during the iteration in `foreach`, it, naturally, raises an exception.

Comment: Ah, by definition it is correct then.  I still feel that it is slightly misleading.  I guess that's the reason for all the controversy (and the reason why they are dropping it from .NET metro, as BoltClock pointed out)?

Comment: @davenewza No, the linked documentation says _Modificare la raccolta sottostante nel corpo di `Action<T>` il delegato non è supportato e non[?] causa un comportamento indefinito._ Or, if one prefers English for some reason: _Modifying the underlying collection in the body of the `Action<T>` delegate is not supported and causes undefined behavior._ So they say you shouldn't modify the `List<>` in the `action` delegate.

Answer (score 5):

`foreach` is a C# language element.  It plays by the rules of C#.

`List<T>.ForEach` is a .NET Framework method.  It plays by the rules of .NET, where `foreach` doesn't exist.

This is an example of "language vs framework" confusion.  Framework methods must work in many languages, and the languages (usually) have contradictory semantics.

Another example of this "language vs framework" confusion is the breaking change to `Enumerable.Cast` between .net 3 and .NET 3.5.  In .NET 3, `Cast` used C# semantics.  In .net 3.5, it was changed to use .net semantics.