# How do I add if statement in Linq statement

Tags: c#

How can I add the if statement that's commented in the code snippet below?

```
Dictionary<string,int> toReturn;
List<string> lookup = GetIt();

foreach (string test in lookup)
{
    var testDictionary = ToGroupDictionary(test);
    testDictionary.Keys.ToList().ForEach(k =>
        //if(true){add toReturn list}
    );
}
```

Comment: You would be better off just using a `foreach` loop -- [`.ForEach` is virtually a deprecated construct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299458/is-the-listt-foreach-extension-method-gone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to add curly braces:

```
testDictionary.Keys.ToList().ForEach(k => 
{
    //if(true){add toReturn list}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Or add a `Where` clause

```
testDictionary
  .Keys
  .Where(k => conditional(k))
  .ForEach(k => { /* something else */ } );
```

Comment: Except for `ForEach` - `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't support that extension. You do require `ToList` in this case.

Comment: *sigh* And that's why we don't open our mouths without double-checking. Side note, while that makes sense (I knew there was a reason I wasn't intimately familiar with the `ForEach` extension), this provides a good justification for _why_ it doesn't support that method - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx