# Why is List<T>.ForEach missing from .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I was porting some code over to work with a Windows Store App and noticed that the `List<T>.ForEach` method isn't included in the .NET Core framework (the framework referenced by Windows Store Apps).

MSDN confirms that it is not supported for Store Apps.

I can easily get around the missing method, but at this point I'm just curious why it's missing.

Comment: Technically, it's not an "extension", it's an ordinary instance method in the `List<T>` class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the List<T>.ForEach() extension method gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299458/is-the-listt-foreach-extension-method-gone)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I can easily get around the missing method, but at this point I'm just curious why it's missing.

I suspect it was deemed unnecessary bloat which arguably would have been better not in the framework to start with, as [using `foreach` is *usually* cleaner](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Indeed, from the link at the bottom of that blog post, MSFT provides an answer in the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/758f7b98-e3ce-41e5-82a2-109f1df446c2):

> `List<T>.ForEach` has been removed in Metro style apps. While the method seems simple it has a number of potential problems when the list gets mutated by the method passed to ForEach. Instead it is recommended that you simply use a foreach loop.

Comment: It appears to have more to do with problems that come with mutating the list within the callback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299458/is-the-listt-foreach-extension-method-gone/10299492#10299492

Comment: @BoltClock: Was just linking to the same original source. I'm not sure that I buy mutation being more of a problem in `ForEach` than `foreach` though - surely it can fail in the same way in both cases.

Comment: Agreed about it adding unnecessary bloat, though. I never really saw the point.

Comment: Perhaps the reasoning was, if you're using foreach, it feels like you're not allowed to mutate the collection, but in a ForEach callback, developers might not feel the same way.

Comment: `foo.thing?.forEach { ... }` is the prime reason it should be included. `foreach(var thing in foo.thing ?? new List<Thing>())` is painful and requires extra unnecessary allocation of a List so you end up having to do an if check outside of the loop.