# Azure Mobile Services - Updating an Entry in the Database

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to update an entry in a table called Request. This table contains columns such as "Name" and "Accepted".
I only want to update the "Accepted" field (which holds a boolean value) so that it becomes true. I only want it to be updated if certain conditions are met, i.e. the "Name" in the database is the same as that in a textbox.

```
private IMobileServiceTable<Request> requestTable= App.appClient.GetTable<Request>();
private MobileServiceCollection<Request, Request> requests;

requests= await requestTable
        .Where(c => c.Name == txtName.Text)
        .ToCollectionAsync();

//what should I put here to update Accepted to true?

await requestTable.UpdateAsync(requests);
```

How can I modify this code so that it will update Accepted to true, but only for the rows where the name matches?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

`codes.ForEach(p => p.Request = true);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately that still isn't working for me. It is giving a red squiggly line under "Foreach" saying that DataModel.Code doesn't contain a definition for 'ForEach'. Is there something that I'm missing from it?

Comment: @PhoenixFirenzy , can you try `ToListAsync` instead of `ToCollectionAsync` or can you typecast `code` to `IEnumerable`  and then try `.ForEach`. ForEach is a lambda expression applies to all ienumerable objects, it should work!

Comment: Yes, you had done, what I told you, It should work, by the way, what is the error? - is it for lambda expression .ForEach?

Comment: @PhoenixFirenzy, make sure you have `using System.Linq` and if still .ForEach is not working, then you can manually use `foeach() {}` loop to do that, ultimately that shortened expression expands to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449160/list-foreach-not-found