# List<T> All rows update

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple model:

```
Id          Name             Hot
----------- ---------------- -----------
1           Nicole           False
2           Samanta          False
3           Sabrina          False
```

I have that list inside a `ListOf<T>`

I want to change the `Hot` property to `True` on all items.

My list have thousands of girls, so I am wondering if I can do it in a different way, avoiding doing the following:

```
foreach(var item in girls)
{
    item.Hot = True;
}
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to avoid that? It seems the most straightforward approach to me. (Admittedly I would have chosen a rather less objectifying example,. personally...)

Comment: There is no way of circumventing the need to change each of the items; in code, this can formulated in either way, but no sensible formulation will yield a substantial improvement over the other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ForEach` method on `List<T>` instead:

```
girls.ForEach(girl => girl.Hot = true);
```

MSDN on that method can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: `ForEach` isn't an extension method. It's a normal method on `List<T>`.

Comment: Actually it is being phased out :)

Comment: Is it really? Do you have a link for that?

Comment: This isnt an offical link, but its already removed in metro style apps. Google has a lot to stay on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299458/is-the-listt-foreach-method-gone   Its easy to roll your own extension tho..But i can see why it was removed. Cant say if this will stick tho. A lot of devs love that method in linq.

Answer (score 4):

No you can not. You need to iterate over and set the property. 
More sexy looking code (considering that we are talking about hot girls) may look like

```
girls.ForEach(g=>g.Hot = true);
```

Worth mentioning that this *does not avoid iteration over collection*, just the syntax changed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the select statement evaluated by `ToList()` due to lazy evaluation

```
girls.Select(g => {g.Hot = True; return g;}).ToList();
```

Comment: @Codor: Well, it's a really inefficient way of doing it - but it *does* modify all the objects referred to by the existing list.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go "the different way":

```
for(int i = 0; i < girls.Count; i++)
{
    girls[i].Hot = True;
}
```

or

```
int i = 0;
while(i < girls.Count)
{
    girls[i].Hot = True;
    i++;
}
```