# How to get Directories name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use this code for get directories name:

```
void DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        foreach (var d in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(d));
            DirSearch(d);
        }
    }
```

but its not get Directory Name. Ex: *"NewFolder1"*, get: *"D:\aaa\bbbb\cccc\dddd\NewFolder1"*.

I have only get Directory Name.

Comment: @Andrei, for that the OP has to use `DirectoryInfo` class, currently `Directory.GetDirectories` will return a `string[]`, which will consist of full path.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach (var d in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\"))
        {
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(d);
            var dirName = dir.Name;

            ListBox1.Items.Add(dirName);
        }
```

Also, you could shortcut...

```
foreach (var d in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\"))
        {
            var dirName = new DirectoryInfo(d).Name;
            ListBox1.Items.Add(dirName);
        }
```

I just used route of **C** for testing.

Answer (score 9):

There is a simple one-liner:

```
Directory.GetDirectories(PathToFolder).Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(d).Name);
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are using [`Directory.GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx), It will return a `string[]` which will consist of full path for the directories. Instead use [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class, later you can use the property `DirectoryInfo.Name` to get *only* the name of the directories and not the full path like:

```
void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sDir);
    foreach (var d in dirInfo.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(d.Name);
    }
}
```

It appears that you are trying to recursively search all the sub directories as well, you can use the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` in your code to include all the sub directories.

Answer (score 2):

How about we use little `linq`:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\").Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(x).Name).ToArray());
```

piece of cake :D

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create `DirectoryInfo` or `FileInfo` classes which can sometimes cause errors and introduce additional overhead, you could do it this way instead:

```
void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    foreach (var d in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(d.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last());
        DirSearch(d);
    }
}
```

It's also a hair bit faster, depending on how many and how large the directories you're searching are...

If you don't need it to be cross-platform/can always guarantee the file system has a slash separator, you can make it a little "shorter"/less verbose.

```
void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    foreach (var d in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(d.TrimEnd('\\').Split('\\').Last());
        DirSearch(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but its not get Directory Name. Ex: "NewFolder1", get: "D:\aaa\bbbb\cccc\dddd\NewFolder1".

[`GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the full path of the directory(it can be used also for files) but you want only the last part, so `NewFolder1` in your example?

You can use [`DirectoryInfo.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
string dir = @"D:\aaa\bbbb\cccc\dddd\NewFolder1";
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
string nameOfDirOnly = dirInfo.Name; // NewFolder1

ListBox1.Items.Add(nameOfDirOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that will work for you...

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetDirInfoFast(string dir, string pattern)
    {
        //you should put try catch here....
        var di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
        var list = new List<string>();
        //put in the pattern
        var dirs = di.GetDirectories(pattern);
        Parallel.ForEach(dirs, p => {
            list.Add(p.Name);
        });
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: [`Parallel.ForEach` is not always faster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6036611/284240). You should also mention why this   solves OP's issue.

Comment: Ya point well taken.  However, when I design anything I always thing about putting something into re-usable libraries, the pattern above is good, but I do admit it's much better when there are thousands of directories.  I answered one just yesterday where OP cut down processing by 4 times using this pattern.

Comment: Also, I'm a LINQ fan too.  I try to write these types of answers to introduce folks to LINQ because, well, it's great!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me as well:

```
var directoryName = Path.GetFileName(directoryPath);
```