# Remove parts of items in combobox VB

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have the code

```
Me.MetroComboBox1.DataSource = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\sampledir\", "*", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

Which is supposed to return the names of folders into a combobox, however when I do, the folders come out as "C\sampledir\samplefolder" instead of "samplefolder". Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Directories name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364708/how-to-get-directories-name)

Comment: Thanks, however I seem to get 'DirectoryInfo' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: `Dim dirNames = Directory.GetDirectories("Your Path", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(Function(d) Path.GetFileName(d)).ToList()`

Comment: take @Jimi code and add `Me.MetroComboBox1.DataSource = dirNames`

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. Return only the name of directory and not her full path

```
Me.MetroComboBox1.DataSource = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\sampledir\", "*",
                                                                   IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(Function(nD) New IO.DirectoryInfo(nD).Name)
```