# "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" why is it showing? And why does the list<>number stop printing?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach

When I execute it, it stops printing at 8 and shows me

> "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

```
List<int> number = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 8, 6};
number.ForEach(delegate (int i) { Console.WriteLine(number[i]); });
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: ForEach passes you the __value__, not the __index__.

Comment: FYI you can also use lambdas to make it shorter `number.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));`

Comment: "it stops printing at 8" yes it should.. and it gives a range exception, because your array is 7 elements 0..6 and your number[5]=8, so number[number[5]] is out range. The tkausl comment is right:  your LINQ returns the values of your array, not the index.

Comment: Do you need the index? If you do and you really don't want to have a classic For loop or a foreach with a counter, there is a 3rd way using a select to get the value and the index  [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vEY26Z)

Comment: Can you link me something that shows how its done? Or if possible show me, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @tkausl already mentioned, *ForEach passes you the value, not the index*, it is not recommended to use `List.ForEach` actually, but if you still want to use it, you can do something like this:

```
 number.ForEach(c => { Console.WriteLine(c); });
```

You can simply use a `foreach` like this:

```
foreach (var c in number)
{
   Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

You can find the discussion here: [foreach vs someList.ForEach(){}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225937/foreach-vs-somelist-foreach)

Comment: what should i use instead ?

Comment: @MohammedDaoudi Just a simple foreach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `foreach` ,
It will never make a mistake

```
List<int> number = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 8, 6 };
foreach (var item in number)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: just wanted to see if it worked that way, but i guess this the best one for it. Thanks.