# Which of these 3 foreach function's should i use? Where is the difference?

Tags: c#, list, class, foreach, constructor

I have 3 foreach function's, writing the list l of type / class Person to Console

```
            foreach(Person p in l)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.first);
                Console.WriteLine(p.last);
            }

            l.ForEach(p =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.first);
                Console.WriteLine(p.last);
            });

            Parallel.ForEach(l, p =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.first);
                Console.WriteLine(p.last);
            });
```

They are all doing the same except that Parallel is working with threading i guess.
What should i use when?

Comment: Multithreading only makes sense when things benefit from said threading. Simple console output doesn't benefit from it. Between the first two it's mostly opinion based

Comment: There is no "should" for any of these. First, you have opinions, the first two are favorites among different people, so you will not get **the** answer, you will only get **an** answer. Secondly, it depends on context, parallel code should only be used when you *want* parallelism, in this case it will probably jumble the output so I would stay away from it. In my opinion, you should use the first piece.

Comment: I would argue that you should just use `foreach` unless you benefit greatly by parallelism, and avoid `List.Foreach()`. It adds no functional benefit, only mildly different syntax. The problem is it _only_ works on `List`. I've seen code that converts an array to a list _just_ to use `ForEach()`, which is dumb.

Comment: Why is it dumb converting an array to a list? Isn't that easier to write in the end after converting an array to a list? Instead of for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)  just the converted array as list .ForEach()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are using a method that is defined on the `List<>` class:

```
l.ForEach(p => { ... });
```

Internally this uses a for `loop` to iterate the collection. Use it when you want shorter and more readable code.

A standard `foreach` provides a bit more control over the loop e.g. breaking out of the loop when a specific condition is met. If want to read more about this just have a look at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225937/foreach-vs-somelist-foreach) which provides in-depth information about this kind of topic.

Compared to the standard `foreach` loop, the `Parallel.ForEach` loop executes in a parallel manner. It uses multiple threads, as you already suggested. Use this when you want to execute multiple processes concurrently. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251874/how-can-i-convert-this-foreach-code-to-parallel-foreach).

```
Parallel.ForEach(l, p => { ... });
```

Comment: `ForEach` is not LINQ. It's defined on `List<T>` only.

Comment: Ah yeah. You're right :) Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit that.

Comment: Nor is it an extension method.

Comment: Moreover,  ForEach is not using foreach loop behind the scene.  Rather it's for loop

Comment: Yup and yup. Sorry for that again. :) I confused this with extension methods that I  implemented some time ago. These were extension methods that used foreach under the hood.