# how to convert foreach loop to lambda expression in c#

Tags: c#

```cs
foreach (IndexingField field in document.IndexingFields)
{
    if (field.TableColumn.ToLower() == "esig"&& field.Data != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.Data.ToString()) && field.Data.ToString() != "N")
    {                               
        EsigBase64Value = field.Data.ToString();
        field.Data = "Y";                                
    }                    
}
```

this is for each loop i am using , i would like to convert this for each loop to lambda expression ,please help me on this

Comment: Why? What is the actual question? You can convert the *contents* of a loop into a lambda and call it but that lambda will look no different from a method or even a local method. If you want to clean up your code, extract the loop block's code into a separate method

Comment: What is `EsigBase64Value`? The way the code is written, it will only contain the contents of the last field after the loop. This is almost certainly a bug

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/225937/1997232). TLDR; you can use `ToList().ForEach()` combo or create extension method yourself.

Comment: What is `field.Data`'s type? Why the calls to `ToString()`? `field.Data.ToString() != "N"` will only work if `Data` is *already* a `string`. The `if` condition could be simplified a *lot*

Comment: EsigBase64Value is string data type

Comment: field.data is of different types(int,bool,string etc..,).when table column is esig ,it will be of string data type and we need that value of esig  in EsigBase64Value

Answer (score 5):

Loops and lambda expressions are different things with different purposes. There is no lambda expression that correlates directly with this intent, and regular LINQ methods like `Select` are intended to perform *projections* (creating new data), not *mutations* (changing existing data).

In short: leave the code alone - it is fine as-is. My main observation would be what the value of `EsigBase64Value` is intended to be when there are zero or multiple records that match the `if` test. You might also want to hoist the `field.Data.ToString()` value, so it only happens once:

```cs
var data = field.Data.ToString();
if (...)
{

}
```

(using `data` in each place where `field.Data.ToString()` appears)

and maybe use a case-insensitive overload of `string.Equals` rather than `field.TableColumn.ToLower() == "esig"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Where`

```
var field = document.IndexingFields.Where(f => f.TableColumn.ToLower() == "esig" && f.Data != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Data.ToString()) && f.Data.ToString() != "N").FirstOrDefault();
```

And after that you can check with `if` condition

```
if (field != null)
 {
   EsigBase64Value = field.Data.ToString();
    field.Data = "Y";    
 }
```

Comment: i have tried above statements.in field we are not getting data property

Comment: @chandra you can try to reduce the checking for null or empty value, some of those are not necessary, for example  ```!string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Data.ToString())```

Comment: see i am not getting issue with those conditions, we are  getting data in field which is of var data type .in that field i am not getting property which is field.data

Comment: @chandra did u use ```.FirstOrDefault()``` ?

Comment: thank you so much it is working after using first or default

Comment: @chandra can you mark it as an answer please, so we can help others