# How to iterate over System.Windows.SystemParameters?

Tags: c#, wpf, parameters

How can I iterate over `System.Windows.SystemParameters` and output all keys and values?

I've found [What is the best way to iterate over a Dictionary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c), but don't know how to adapt the code for `SystemParameters`.

Perhaps you could also explain how I could have figured it out by myself; maybe by using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using reflection you can create a dictionary by inspecting all the properties

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var type = typeof (System.Windows.SystemParameters);
var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

foreach(var property in properties)
{
    result.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(null, null));
}

foreach(var pair in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

This will produce the following output...

FocusBorderWidth : 1
FocusBorderHeight : 1
HighContrast : False
FocusBorderWidthKey : FocusBorderWidth
FocusBorderHeightKey : FocusBorderHeight
HighContrastKey : HighContrast
DropShadow : True
FlatMenu : True
WorkArea : 0,0,1681,1021
DropShadowKey : DropShadow
FlatMenuKey : FlatMenu

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, SystemParameters doesn't implement any kind of Enumerable interface, so none of the standard iteration coding idioms in C# will work just like that.

However, you can use **Reflection** to get all the public static properties of the class:

```
var props = typeof(SystemParameters)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

You can then iterate over `props`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about SystemParameters not implementing any kind of Enumerable interface!

Answer (score 1):

May be better way to iterate through reflected set of proprties using Type.GetProperties

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary contains a KeyValuePair so something like this should work

```
foreach (KeyValuePair kvp in System.Windows.SystemParameters)
{
  var myvalue = kvp.value;
}
```

Having said that the help on msdn does not mention anything about System.Windows.SystemParameters being a dictionary

Comment: ...but, SystemParameters is not a Dictionary, so this will not work.