# How do I get key/value of a Dictionnary with an Iterator?

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
//mDIco is a Dictionnary with string as keys and homemade class (cAsso) as values
IEnumerator iterdico = mDico.GetEnumerator();

iterdico.Reset();

while (iterdico.MoveNext())
{
    var asso = iterdico.Current as cAsso;
    if (asso != null)
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

I thought this would work, but obviously it doesnt. So how I do i get access to the class which is contained into the value of my dictionnary?

Comment: Is the iterator imperative? You could do this very easily with a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are relying on the non-generic [`IEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator) interface, which doesn't reveal the real element-type (its `Current` property is of type `object`). Use the generic interface ([`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb), which does make the element-type easily discoverable) instead, and you will be fine.

Of course, you don't need any special effort for this. The `Dictionary<,>` class implements the `IEnumerable` interface *explicitly*. Its 'implicit' `GetEnumerator` method returns an enumerator that is strongly typed (a nested type that implements the generic interface), which is what we want.

So it's fine to use implicit typing all the way and let the compiler figure things out.

```
// Actually a Dictionary<string, cAsso>.Enumerator
// which in turn is an IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, cAsso>>
using(var iterdico = mDico.GetEnumerator())
{
   while (iterdico.MoveNext())
   {
       // var = KeyValuePair<string, cAsso>
       var kvp = iterdico.Current;

       // var = string
       var key = kvp.Key;

       // var = cAsso
       var value = kvp.Value;
       ...
   }
}
```

EDIT:

A few other peripheral points:

1. In general, you should `Dispose` of enumerators, typically with a `using` block.
2. The use of the `Reset` method on enumerators is not recommended. In fact, in this particular case, it is useless.
3. Note that the element-type of the dictionary's enumerator is a Key-Value *pair*, not the value itself. if you are only interested in the values, enumerate the sequence returned by the dictionary's `Value` property.
4. As Davide Piras points out, in most cases, you just want a normal `foreach` loop instead of messing around with the enumerator yourself.

Comment: @David Yaw: Yes, so? As you can see, I'm getting the key and value out from the KVPs separately.

Comment: Thanks alot, it is all the infos I needed.

Comment: I am surprised that this answer has very few upvotes though it gives a very balanced and type safe way of handling this as compared to [this answer on another SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/141098/365188).

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, cAsso> kvp in mDico)
{
    // kvp.Key is string
    // kvp.Value is cAsso
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var kvp in mDico)
{
    var asso = kvp.Value;
    ...
}
```