# Getting values from dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Dictionary<int, int> in my class. How can I access both values without knowing the key?

For instance, I want to be able to do something like this: If the dictionary contains Dictionary<int, int>
and the values are <5, 4>
I want to be able to get the value of <(this),(this)> like

Pseudo code:

```
foreach(Dictionary item or row)
{
    my first int = Dictionary<(this), (not this)>
    my second int = Dictionary<(not this), (this)>
}
```

How can I do this using a dictionary? If this is not doable: Is there another way?

Comment: Sounds like `Dictionary` is not the right abstraction for your use case.

Comment: I need a good suggestion then  :)

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I read 5 times and still don't know what you want...

Comment: Sure... Basically I created a Dictionary to contain two ints.. the problem is that I think the first item is the key and I would really want to be able to retrieve both values like I explained above ... I should be able to get the first "int" if I wanted to.. or the "second" just like an array.. I am new to c# so bare with me

Comment: Perhaps if you explained more about the data your access (real world) and the access patterns.  I don't get the (not this} and I don't understand why you're storing a dictionary of dicationaries

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a List<int> to get to the ints?  A dictionary is a lookup table - like the index in a book.  Its used to look up a value by a key.

Comment: I am not storing Dictionary of Dictionaries but someone that provided the answer below understood my issue.. thanks

Comment: If i were to use a List, I would needed to be List<int, int> is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to iterate over a Dictionary in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c)

Comment: You could do a List<MyObject>, where MyObject has 2 int properties (or use a List<Tuple<int, int>>). Dictionary indicates that the first int (the key) is unique in the collection. If you could have, say, <1,2> and <1,3> in your collection you should not use a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in myDictionary)
{
   var first = kvp.Key;
   var second = kvp.Value;
}
```