# Applying a function to every field in a class

Tags: c#

This is an interesting concept which i couldn't figure out how to implement. (its related to a university assignment where i need to deploy the decorator pattern).

I've written rough C# code below which won't compile however, Suppose, i have a class

```
Class A {
   public int A { get; set; }
   public string B { get; set; }
   public float C { get; set; }

   public string concatFields() {
       string sample = null;
       foreach (Field f in this) {
           sample += f.ToString();
       }
       return sample;
   }
}
```

How in terms would you achieve the concatFields method? Is there a way to iterate through the class's fields (without knowing the names of the fields) and call ToString() on each.

In example B scenario, how would you apply the same method on all Fields provided they were the same type.

Cheers guys for the help, i've tagged this with C# but not sure what other tags could be applied

Comment: The concept you are looking for is called "Reflection"

Comment: Please check out this example on [dotnetpearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/reflection-field) it gives a pretty straightforward example (with code) of doing exactly what you are asking for using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), iterate over metadata of your class, and pull fields through the reflection API. Obviously, there is a cost attached to that: using reflection is slower than accessing fields directly; sometimes, considerably. However, you can certainly do it. Here is an example:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
// Set fields in the obj...
var fields = typeof(MyClass).GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField);
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
foreach (FieldInfo f in fields) {
    var val = f.GetValue(obj);
    if (val != null) res.Append(val.ToString());
}
Console.WriteLine(res.ToString());
```

[`FieldInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.aspx) class exposes many useful properties, such as `Name` and `Type`, letting you pick which fields to include in your processing, and which fields to ignore.

Comment: It is very important to use `.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField)` or you will get an Exception trying to read a field with no getter.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Thanks for the important note! As a side note, if you see a 100% certain change like this one, feel free to edit the answer: if an author does not like the change, he or she can always revert your edits. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Put your 'fields' in a dictionary.

And here's how to iterate a dictionary: [What is the best way to iterate over a Dictionary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c)

Comment: I think they want to avoid the manual effort. They'll probably need to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET/C#, type introspection is handled via the [System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) namespace. This allows you to retrieve information about types, and dynamically invoke methods that are unknown at compile time.

> How in terms would you achieve the concatFields method? Is there a way to iterate through the class's fields (without knowing the names of the fields) and call ToString() on each.

```
public string concatFields() {
   string sample = null; // a StringBuilder would be a better choice here
   foreach (FieldInfo f in this.GetType().GetFields()) {
       obj fieldValue = f.GetValue();
       if (fieldValue != null) sample += fieldValue.ToString();
   }
   return sample;
}
```

> In example B scenario, how would you apply the same method on all Fields provided they were the same type.

If you know the type at compile time, you can cast to it:

```
foreach (FieldInfo f in this.GetType().GetFields()) {
    MyType myType = (MyType)f.GetValue();
    myType.MyMethod();
}
```

Or, you can dynamically invoke via reflection:

```
foreach (FieldInfo f in this.GetType().GetFields()) {
    object fieldValue = f.GetValue();
    MethodInfo mi = fieldValue.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod");
    mi.Invoke(fieldValue, null); // no parameters to MyMethod
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this:

```
class A

{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public float C { get; set; }

    public string[] concatFields()
    {
        var v = from f in this.GetType().GetFields() select f;
        IList<string> fields = new List<string>();
        foreach (var f in v)
        {
            fields.Add(f.GetValue(this).ToString());
        }
        return fields.ToArray<string>();
    }
}
```