# Looping through dictionary object

Tags: c#, .net

I am very new to .NET, used to working in PHP. I need to iterate via `foreach` through a dictionary of objects. My setup is an MVC4 app.

The Model looks like this:

```
public class TestModels
{
    Dictionary<int, dynamic> sp = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>
    {
        {1, new {name="abc", age="1"}},
        {2, new {name="def", age="2"}}
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
   Models.TestModels obj = new Models.TestModels();
}
```

How do I loop through the `obj` object and retrieve the values of the dictionary and print them in the view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to iterate over a Dictionary in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c)

Comment: (I voted as a duplicate as well: just keep in mind that iteration order is not defined ..)

Answer (score 55):

One way is to loop through the keys of the dictionary, which I recommend:

```
foreach(int key in sp.Keys)
    dynamic value = sp[key];
```

Another way, is to loop through the dictionary as a sequence of pairs:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, dynamic> pair in sp)
{
    int key = pair.Key;
    dynamic value = pair.Value;
}
```

I recommend the first approach, because you can have more control over the order of items retrieved if you decorate the `Keys` property with proper LINQ statements, e.g., `sp.Keys.OrderBy(x => x)` helps you retrieve the items in ascending order of the key. Note that `Dictionary` uses a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) data structure internally, therefore if you use the second method the order of items is not easily predictable.

**Update (01 Dec 2016)**: replaced `var`s with actual types to make the answer more clear.

Comment: so is to be done in the View ? Also value will contain both the values right ? so then I just have to do value.0 and value.1 to print ?

Comment: No. You would do it like in my answer, or based on Sina's answer you would call it using `value` and the name you gave the variable, e.g. `value.name` or `value.age`.

Comment: small point: it'd make this a little easier to understand if the var keyword wasn't used

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you are after in the Dictionary

```
Models.TestModels obj = new Models.TestModels();

foreach (var keyValuPair in obj.sp)
{
    // KeyValuePair<int, dynamic>
}

foreach (var key in obj.sp.Keys)
{
     // Int 
}

foreach (var value in obj.sp.Values)
{
    // dynamic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
Models.TestModels obj = new Models.TestModels();
foreach (var item in obj.sp)
{
    Console.Write(item.Key);
    Console.Write(item.Value.name);
    Console.Write(item.Value.age);
}
```

The problem you most likely have right now is that the collection is [private](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). If you add [public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yzh058ae%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to the beginning of this line

```
Dictionary<int, dynamic> sp = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>
```

You should be able to access it from the function inside your controller.

***Edit**: Adding functional example of the full `TestModels` implementation.*

Your `TestModels` class should look something like this.

```
public class TestModels
{
    public Dictionary<int, dynamic> sp = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>();

    public TestModels()
    {
        sp.Add(0, new {name="Test One", age=5});
        sp.Add(1, new {name="Test Two", age=7});
    }
}
```

You probably want to read up on the [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) keyword as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestModels
{
    public Dictionary<int, dynamic> sp = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>();

    public TestModels()
    {
        sp.Add(0, new {name="Test One", age=5});
        sp.Add(1, new {name="Test Two", age=7});
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .