# How to iterate over a list dictionaries and print their content?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, listiterator

I am a c# newbie and I figured out to get a response from an API using **HttpClient** and with the following code I got the JSON from the server shown below:

```
class Program
{
    public class Parameter
    {
        public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
        public Establecimiento Establecimiento { get; set; }
    }
    public class Usuario
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }

    public class Establecimiento
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class deliveryData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string establecimiento_id { get; set; }
        public string numero_orden { get; set; }
        public string ciudad_id { get; set; }
        public string fecha { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception details: " + e.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://it-215...web.development.co/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            try
            {
                // HTTP POST
                var json = new Parameter
                {
                    Establecimiento = new Establecimiento
                    {
                        id = 147
                    },
                    Usuario = new Usuario
                    {
                        email = "user@email.com",
                        password = "something"
                    }
                };

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/service", json);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();    // Throw if not a success code.
                string responseBodyAsText;
                responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBodyAsText);

                //List<Dictionary<string, deliveryData>> decodedDeliveries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, deliveryData>>>(responseBodyAsText);

                //foreach (var delivery in decodedDeliveries)
                //{
                //    Console.WriteLine(delivery.ToString());
                //}

            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception details: " + e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JSON response until here:

```
[   {
    "PedidosOnline": {
      "id": "7491031",
      "establecimiento_id": "147",
      "numero_orden": "1769629-20160509211442",
      "fecha": "2016-05-09 21:14:42"
    }   
    },   {
    "PedidosOnline": {
      "id": "7491328",
      "establecimiento_id": "147",
      "numero_orden": "1559397-20160509212644",
      "fecha": "2016-05-09 21:26:44"
    }   
} ]
```

Now when I comment the

> Console.WriteLine(responseBodyAsText);

and uncomment the decoding line and the foreach, this is what I get:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,ProjectName.Program+deliveryData]
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,ProjectName.Program+deliveryData]
```

What I want is to get a clean print of the fields viewed in the JSON, since my next step is to save every field of the dictionaries in an Access DB (which I've no idea how to do but I'll figure it out). So I need a little help with this, any advice will be much apprecated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719955/looping-through-dictionary-object

Comment: You are deserializing into a `List<Dictionary<string, deliverydata>>`? Don't you mean `Dictionary<string, deliverydata>`? Then to print its just `Console.WriteLine(item.key + " " + item.value);`

Comment: @MethodMan I'd personally recommend [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/141098/6352535) answer/thread instead

Comment: @CallbackKid thanks for your input. The list is necessary though since I am creating a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing the `Dictionary` objects themselves, loop through each `Dictionary` and print every key-value pair.

```
List<Dictionary<string, deliveryData>> decodedDeliveries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, deliveryData>>>(responseBodyAsText);

foreach (var delivery in decodedDeliveries)
{
  foreach(var pair in delivery) {
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + " : " + pair.Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also add additional prints within the loop if you wish, so that it prints in a JSON format.

Comment: thanks for your reply, this answers my question and it worked. When I get the reputation to upvote your answer I will upvote.

Comment: Glad to hear it @andres_v could you mark my answer as correct in the meantime?