# declare variable as a field of the class

Tags: c#, class, field

Using C#
This is a basic question I'm sure.  I'm getting the error.. "The name '_stocks' does not exist in the current context".  I know this is because I declared the _stocks dictionary within the Initialize method. This makes the _stocks variable a local variable and only accessible within the Initialize method. I need to declare the _stocks variable as a field of the class (so it can be accessed by any method of the class).  The other method as you will see below is OnBarUpdate().  How do I go about declaring the _stocks variable as a field of the class?

```
public class MAcrossLong : Strategy
{
    //Variables
    private int variable1 = 0
    private int variable2 = 0

    public struct StockEntry
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public PeriodType Period { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {                       
        Dictionary<string, StockEntry> _stocks = new Dictionary<string, StockEntry>();

        _stocks.Add("ABC", new StockEntry { Name = "ABC", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 5, Count = 0 } );
    }

    protected override void OnBarUpdate()
    {
       //_stocks dictionary is used within the code in this method.  error is occurring         within this method
    }
}
```

******Added Portion....

I should probably just post the code within OnBarUpdate() because I'm now getting other errors...
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.this[string]' has some invalid arguments
Argument '1': cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'
Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NinjaTrader.Strategy.MAcrossLong.StockEntry' and 'int'

```
protected override void OnBarUpdate()

        {  //for loop to iterate each instrument through
for (int series = 0; series < 5; series++)
if (BarsInProgress == series)
{  
var singleStockCount = _stocks[series];
bool enterTrade = false;
   if (singleStockCount < 1)
{
enterTrade = true;
}
else
{
enterTrade = BarsSinceEntry(series, "", 0) > 2; 
} 

                if (enterTrade)
 {  // Condition for Long Entry here


                  EnterLong(200);
{
 if(_stocks.ContainsKey(series))
{
_stocks[series]++;
}
}
 }
            } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you declared `variable1` and `variable2`....

```
public class MAcrossLong : Strategy
{
   private int variable1 = 0;
   private int variable2 = 0;
   private Dictionary<string, StockEntry> _stocks;

   protected override void Initialize()
   {
      _stocks.Add("ABC", new StockEntry { Name = "ABC", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 5, Count = 0 } );
   }

   protected override void OnBarUpdate()
   {
      _stocks["ABC"].Name = "new name"; // Or some other code with _stocks
   }
}
```

---

To fix the error inside the `OnBarUpdate()` that you recently added, you need to switch to a `foreach` loop and use a `KeyValuePair<string, StockEntry>` iterator. You can read more on them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c).

It should look something like this:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, StockEntry> stock in _stocks)
{
   string ticker = stock.Key;
   StockEntry stockEntry = stock.Value;
   // Or some other actions with stock
}
```

Comment: I added the OnBardUpdate() code to my original post at the bottom of the post.  I posted the other errors I'm getting now.  Is it a simple fix?  thanks

Comment: Your added portion is a separate problem and should be posted as a new question. The problem lies in that you don't access a dictionary via an index like normal arrays or lists. You access via its key which you defined as a string. Look into `foreach` loops and use `KeyValuePair<string, StockEntry>` as the iterator.

Comment: So use for each and replace series with KeyValuePair<string, StockEntry> ?

Comment: I'm still struggling with this a bit.  If one of my conditions for entering a stock trade is..if (SMA(BarsArray[series],Fast)[1] > SMA(BarsArray[series],Slow)[1]) staying in line with what you have above how can I adjust this and have each stock iterate through this condition?  I assume I can't use BarsArray any longer.  And would "series" be replaced with "stock" that your using above?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. Read up on the links I provided so you understand how `foreach` and `KeyValuePair` work. If you still have trouble post in a new question with what you have tried and why it's not working because this is a completely separate topic from the original.

Comment: Instead of using a string for the dictionary key, im going to use int like so..Dictionary<int, StockEntry> _stocks = new Dictionary<int, StockEntry>(); and then add stocks to the dictionary as.. _stocks.Add(0, new StockEntry { Name = "ABC", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 5, Count = 0 } );  This way I can still iterate with the index values and not have to change my whole script.  You think that will work?

Comment: If you want to use an `int` as an index then use a `List` instead of a `Dictionary`. This will allow you to iterate with a standard `for` loop.

Comment: The struct im using above will not work?

Comment: This is the last time I'm going to say it and respond because it is obvious you haven't read the documentation like I keep referring to.... You can use the struct. A `List` is generic just like a `Dictionary`.

Comment: No need to get rude, I did read the documentation thanks.  Just see no reason to have to fix what's not broken.  The docs discuss complicated ways that I don't need such as using a keyvalue, and a simple foreach loops that I'm already aware of but I don't need.  All this has done is just wasted my time.  Thanks for tryn to help though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `_stocks` in a class level scope. Since you have declared it within the Initialize method its visibility becomes local to that method. So you should declare it along with `variable1` and `variable2` like

```
private int variable1 = 0;
private int variable2 = 0;
private Dictionary<string, StockEntry> _stocks;
```

You might need to look into the [Access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) and [Variable and Method Scopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) for a better understanding

Comment: I added the OnBardUpdate() code to my original post at the bottom of the post.  I posted the other errors I'm getting now.  Is it a simple fix?  thanks