# Parsing WordPress REST API post tags

Tags: c#, json, wordpress, .net-4.5

I'm attempting to get the categories and tags related to a WordPress post.

It's a self-hosted installation with the Jetpack plugin installed and working, so I'm using the [WordPress.com Rest API](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) to query.

[Here's some example JSON](https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/?number=5&pretty=1) which the REST API returns for `/posts`

You'll note that the first post returned in the above example (at the time of writing) is tagged `facebook`, `Google`, `Publicize`, `Sharing` and `twitter`.

However there's something of an inconsistency with how the JSON is formatted. Instead of being represented as an array with every object in the array having consistent properties (name, slug, description) - allowing me to simply iterate the array - each tag seems to be represented as its own object, with the object's name being the name of the tag. Here's how it shows in the [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/):

[image: Visualisation of JSON data]

So, without knowing the tags in advance, it presents a challenge of how to get the post's tags.

I'm using .NET 4.5's `HttpClient` so I've worked around it, of a fashion, using the `dynamic` type:

```
public class WordpressBlogPost : IBlogPost
    {
        // IBlogPost implementation
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Excerpt { get; set; }
        public dynamic Tags { get; set; }
        public string Featured_Image { get; set; }
        public int Comment_Count { get; set; }
    }
```

You can then iterate Tags, were each is a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty` and access the name, slug, etc. like so:

```
foreach (var wordpressPost in parseJsonResult.posts)
{
    foreach (var tag in wordpressPost.Tags)
    {
        string tagName = tag.Value.name;
        string tagSlug = tag.Value.slug;
    }
}
```

However, it feels quite hacky, and I'd like a cleaner way of doing it.

So - does anyone know -

1. Can I send some sort of querystring parameter or do something else to get it to return a collection?
2. Is there a nicer way in .NET than using the `dynamic` type so I can have strongly typed tags?

Answer (score 0):

Objects in JSON are in fact associative arrays (aka: hash, dictionaries), and you can loop on them, just like any other array.

In C#, you can do so like this:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in MyDic)
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c

Hoping this will help.