# Modifying the contents of a Dictionary in foreach loop

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

I am trying to update the contents of a C# Dictionary in a foreach loop, when a certain condition is met.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Corpus_22_04_2014_StreetTable_Row> entry in id_StreetNameDictionary)
{
    if(something_happens())
    {
         Corpus_22_04_2014_StreetTable_Row r = entry.Value;
         //Modify r
         id_StreetNameDictionary[entry.Key] = r;
    }
}
```

This throws an InvalidOperationException stating that "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.". It seems that we are not allowed to modify the contents of a Dictionary in foreach loop.

What can be a possible workaround to that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c see the third answer here

Comment: Poor choice on close, Anthony.  The suggestion here should be to modify the element's data directly.  It isn't the Dictionary that should be modified, but the _Row_ that it contains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `ToList` on the dictionary to copy each key-value pair into a list. Then iterate over that list instead of `Dictionary`:

```
foreach (var entry in id_StreetNameDictionary.ToList())
{
    if(something_happens())
    {
         Corpus_22_04_2014_StreetTable_Row r = entry.Value;
         //Modify r
         id_StreetNameDictionary[entry.Key] = r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a list of all the keys and iterate that. For example:

```
foreach (var key in id_StreetNameDictionary.Keys.ToList())
{
    if(something_happens())
    {
         var r = id_StreetNameDictionary[key];
         //Modify r
         id_StreetNameDictionary[key] = r;
    }
}
```

This will be somewhat more memory efficient than creating a list of `KeyValuePair` structures from the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears you really want to modify the *row* and not necessarily the `Dictionary`, then do so directly:

```
foreach (var entry in id_StreetNameDictionary)
{
    if (something_happens())
    {
        ((Corpus_22_04_2014_StreetTable_Row)entry.Value)["FieldToChange"] = newValue;
        //...repeat for each field to change...you will be altering the row directly, no need to reassign it
    }
}
```

Comment: Already tried to directly modify the 'entry.Value' but the compiler says that "Cannot modify because entry.Value is not a variable". I think that the Dictionary entries are meant to be hold as constants.

Answer (score 0):

Well I use the following workaround. Not very efficient maybe, but it does the work.
I declare three dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<int, Corpus_22_04_2014_StreetTable_Row> id_StreetNameDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Corpus_22_04_2014_StreetTable_Row>();
Dictionary<int, Corpus_22_04_2014_StreetTable_Row> tempDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Corpus_22_04_2014_StreetTable_Row>();
Dictionary<int, Corpus_22_04_2014_StreetTable_Row> swapBuffer;
```

I completely dump the old dictionary, with all modified and unmodified key/value pairs, into the tempDictionary. Then I swap both dictionaries and clear the unused one:

```
foreach (var entry in id_StreetNameDictionary)
{
    Corpus_22_04_2014_StreetTable_Row row = id_StreetNameDictionary[entry.Key];
    if (something_happens())
    {

        //Modify row
    }
    tempDictionary.Add(row.id, row);

}

swapBuffer = tempDictionary;
tempDictionary = id_StreetNameDictionary;
id_StreetNameDictionary = swapBuffer;
tempDictionary.Clear();
```