# Parsing a generic variable from a Json text

Tags: c#, json, parsing, dynamic

I'm trying to parse the info from a json object obtained via api, but in this request, I'm trying to get just one variable. I just want to get the `summonerLevel` variable.

```
{
 "test": { 
    "id":107537,
    "name":"test",
    "profileIconId":785,
    "summonerLevel":30,
    "revisionDate":1440089189000
 }
}
```

I've been trying to it with this code and I know that if I write

```
p.summonerLevel = (int)(obj.test.summonerLevel)
```

it will work, but the problem is that `test` is not a static name, and it will be changing within each request I do. Any good example on how to do it?
Thanks

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
string data = c.DownloadString("https://las.api.pvp.net/api/lol/las/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"+summonerName+"?api_key=<api-key>");
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
p.summonerLevel = (int)(obj.tempName.summonerLevel);
```

Comment: I´ve also tried this. :
 p.summonerLevel = (int)obj[p.summonerName]["summonerLevel"];

Comment: The JSON structure implies that you need to deserialize it as `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`, then you can easily access the first key.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c

Comment: Is there only ever the one property in your root object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
int  summonerLevel= (int)JObject.Parse(data).First.First["summonerLevel"];
```

Comment: Thanks, u genius. Its just hard to me to understand this json parsing. might need some read.