# Dictionary ForAll / ForEach method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, iteration

What is the proper `ForAll` method for the `Dictionary` object? I am learning the Linq type iteration (method 1 below), but do not getting it to work. The old `foreach` loop works (method 2 below). Despite many answers on similar questions, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c), I do not see a Linq iteration solution.

The Dictionary seems to have methods to get all Keys or all Values, usable in the Linq iteration, but not to get all KeyValuePairs. Strange!

I did some fiddling with `GetEnumeration()`, but without much luck.

The `AsParallel()` method seemed the solution, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30782291/1845672), but with me I only got a build error: Dictionary does not contain a definition for AsParallel .

One could argue that Method 2 does not have so much more lines of source, but to me the Linq iteration of Method 1 is still more simple, more direct, more elegant.

Is there still an easy way to make Method 1 work?

Version: .Net Framework 4.5.2

```
using System.Linq;//AsParallel, ToList
using System.Collections.Generic;//Dictionary
using System.Xml.Linq;//XElement
using System.IO;//Path, Dir, File

        public Dictionary<string, string> DictUserConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public void SaveFile(string FileName)
        {
            XDocument XDConf = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));
#if true//method 1: problem: Dictionary does not have a .ForAll or .ForEach method, or .GetEnumerator().ForAll(x => ...)
            XDConf.Add(
                new XElement("settings",
                    DictUserConfig.ForEach(x =>
                        new XElement("add",
                            new XAttribute("key", x.Key),
                            new XAttribute("value", x.Value)))));
#else//method 2: works
            XElement XSettings = new XElement("settings");
            XDConf.Add(XSettings);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> x in DictUserConfig)
            {
                XSettings.Add(
                    new XElement("add",
                        new XAttribute("key", x.Key),
                        new XAttribute("value", x.Value)));
            }
#endif
            XDConf.Save(FileName);
            return;
        }
```

---

Update:
I discovered one problem: missing `using System.Linq`, removed some time ago when I didn't need that. Discovered by testing the several useful comments on my post.

Now the problem is more easily summarized as:

This works:

```
DictUserConfig.ToList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Key + x.Value));
DictUserConfig.AsParallel().ForAll(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Key + x.Value));
```

But this does not work:

```
XElement XE1 =  (XElement)DictUserConfig.ToList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>().ForEach(x => new XElement(x.Key, x.Value));
XElement XE2 =  DictUserConfig.AsParallel().ForEach(x => new XElement(x.Key, x.Value));
```

And the reason is, I suppose, that ToList and AsParallel do not return the result of the ForEach back to the `this`. The build error is: cannot convert void to object (or XElement). So the only 'solution' seems to create ForEach myself using the one-liner, which is already showing as a solution, but taking care to return an XElement object.

---

After testing the final answer, I would like to note that the discussion is not about the relative values of ForEach versus foreach, but that this obscured the real solution of Select. Also, foreach is more the Fortran way of making something happen, and ForEach, and especially Select, rather about what you want to achieve.

I would like to thank everyone for the comments and answers, of which I learned something today.

Comment: [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) is a good read. If you still want one you can easily implement it yourself.

Comment: `ForEach` dont work that way.

Comment: Why it must be LinQ? it slower than normal `foreach`

Comment: @SimonKarlsson indeed, explains why my question has no solution. But I do not agree, especially with `new Element()` I find ForEach more suitable than foreach. Perhaps matter of taste, but why do we have Linq queries at all?

Comment: The `ForEach` is actually not a part of LINQ.

Comment: @Sakura I am not concerned about performance, see no reason why ForEach would be slow. And I am trying to learn something here, otherwise I might as well live with foreach.

Comment: You mention a build error with `AsParallel` but you do not say what the error is.  If you identify what the error is there may be a simple solution.

Comment: You can always spool out a dictionary into a `List<KeyValuePair>` by calling the `ToList()` extension method.

Comment: The proper LINQ solution for how to perform an action on each item in a sequence *is to use `foreach`*.  Creating a method to do it is *contrary* to the principles of LINQ, which is why there is none, intentionally.  Just use a `foreach`, it's the proper solution to this problem.

Comment: @DStanley I added the build error msg to the question: Dictionary does not have such definition

Comment: @code4life ToList() : Dictionary does not contain such definition :-( similar to lack of ForEach I suppose

Comment: Read this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: @SimonKarlsson I did not manage to create the 'simple 1-liner' for that missing method. Would appreciate to learn how

Comment: Here is perspective: in `foreach` you can get each item and evaluate. in `ForAll` - you modifying actual items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each `KeyValuePair<string,string>` you want to create and return a new `XElement` with proper attributes. This is called a **projection**.

[**`Select`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `LINQ`'s projection method:

```
XDConf.Add(new XElement("settings",
    DictUserConfig.Select(
        kvp => new XElement("add", 
            new XAttribute("key", kvp.Key),
            new XAttribute("value", kvp.Value)))/*.
   Cast<object>().ToArray()*/));
```

<del>The cast at the end is necessary to call the correct constructor of `XElement`.</del>

---

Note that `List<T>.ForEach` iterates over the enumeration and calls an `Action<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` for each `KeyValuePair`. But it does not return anything, so you cannot use it in your `XElement` constructor call.

Comment: This. `Select` *is* the LINQ method for mapping each element x to some element y.

Comment: Why would you spend the cycles to create a projection when you can just call `ToList()`?

Comment: @code4life Why would you create a list that's you're just going to immediately throw away, when you could just not do that?

Comment: @code4life because `List<T>.ForEach` returns `void` and not an `object[]` as needed for the `XElement(string name, params object[] content)` constructor.

Comment: @Servy: you're not throwing the list away, you're going to iterate through it via `ForEach`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @code4life you miss that OP wants to return new elements. This _is_ a projection.

Comment: @code4life The underlying sequence is already iteratable.  So you're creating a list and doing nothing with it that you couldn't do with the underlying sequence, thus wasting the effort of creating the list and materializing the entire sequence.

Comment: @Servy: sorry, I was reading way too fast. I see what you're doing now. But I think it's still worthwhile to provide some educational info on how to use `ToList()` to access `ForEach`. It falls along the principle of "give a man a fish, you feed him for a day, but teach him to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime".

Comment: @RenéVogt Indeed! I just discovered that myself, and added to the question. List() returns a new list and the return value gets lost. Similar AsParallel().

Comment: @RenéVogt Took some discussion at the other answer, but this is the simple solution. The cast at the end seems not needed in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ToList extension method in order to get a list of KeyValuePairs that is compatible with the ForEach method.

```
Dictionary<string, int> testDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
testDict.Add("one", 1);
testDict.Add("two", 2);
testDict.Add("three", 3);

testDict.ToList<KeyValuePair<string, int>>().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Key));
```

DotNetFiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5rRGZc

I would agree with the comment by Sakura that the normal foreach is probably the better choice, though.

Comment: The OP was asking for how to get a list of kvp, and this does the job! +1

Comment: Thanks! Although not the final solution, testing this example made me find the missing 'using System.Linq' in my source.

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach()` is a specific method of `List<T>` class.

But you can make your own extensor method of `Dictionary<TKey, TVakue>`:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, Action<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in dict)
            action(item);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
XElement XSettings = new XElement("settings");
DictUserConfig.ForEach(x =>
    XSettings.Add(new XElement("add",
            new XAttribute("key", (string)x.Key),
            new XAttribute("value", (string)x.Value))));
```

**UPDATE**:

Using method 1, then you can use an extensor like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ForEach<TKey, TValue, TResult>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, TResult> func)
{
    foreach (var item in dict)
        yield return func(item);
}
```

Then method 1 would be:

```
XDConf.Add(new XElement("settings",
                DictUserConfig.ForEach(x =>
                    new XElement("add", new XAttribute("key", x.Key),
                                        new XAttribute("value", x.Value))).ToArray()));
```

Probably a `Cast<object>()` would be necessary before `ToArray()`.

Comment: @code4life So everytime the dictionary is iterated it also needs to be converted to a list first, seems efficient.

Comment: @code4life: Yes, I know. it's just to have a foreach to the dictionary itself and not have to convert it each time is required

Comment: We are getting close now. In the use example both commands should be combined, saving one semicolon, by changing the definition for ForEach with a Func<> instead of the Action<>, returning a List<XElement>, better: List<T>. I am working on it, but would be glad to accept your updated answer.

Comment: @Roland: I updated my answer but I'm not sure if this is what you need.

Comment: Excellent solution! Exactly what I was originally looking for! I just made a similar solution, but with more code, so I am glad I resisted the temptation to edit your original answer with my solution. Question: is it really necessary to supply TKey, TValue, TResult as arguments? The inner code should already know the types used in the dictionary 'this', and the result type of func?

Comment: The proposed 'Cast' and the ToArray() are not needed. App works without that.

Comment: @Roland: Yes, it is necessary, because in parameters you can not declare generics types, you have to do it in the method definition. It's the syntax of C#.

Comment: @Roland: but if this is what you want, i think you can use Select(), does exactly the same as this ForEach() implementation.

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca As much as I appreciate the code in your Answer, Select() indeed does exactly the same (as I tested), but simpler. Disappointing to discover this after so much trouble, but fun that C# isn't that bad after all. Now I'll have to credit some earlier commenters too.

Comment: @Roland: My original answer was using Select() but was downvoted so I deleted it thinking it was not what you wanted.

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca Indeed we arrived at the final solution with a detour. Rene's answer shows a more complete code example. But I upvoted your contributions!