# Finding the number of odd/even values in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary, let's it key value pair be as follow:

```
a - 1
b - 3
c - 2
```

I want to find out the number of odd and even value chars. For example, the above will return me 2 odd and 1 even.

I was thinking of iterating but I read iterating is the wrong way if we are using a dictionary. What is the best approach?

Comment: Where did you read " iterating is the wrong way if we are using a dictionary"? If iterating over a dictionary is bad then it probably wouldn't implement IEnumerable/Enumerator.

Comment: one stackover flow comment before writing this question. sorry, don't have the link though

Comment: Those values are integer not char.   Value in Dictionary is not indexed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use LINQ:

```
var numOdd = myDic.Count(e => e.Value % 2 == 1);
```

Comment: @John It's still iterating over the dictionary, though (granted I don't think it's possible to avoid iterating over the dictionary and do what you want)

Answer (score 0):

See this link [What is the best way to iterate over a Dictionary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c) , iterating internally or externally is needed.

The code should be something like following. It first identifies the number of evens, then the number of odd will be total elements minus event numbers.

```
 int evenCounter=0; 
   foreach(var item in myDictionary.Values)
    {
      if(item %2 ==0)
       evenCounter++;
    }

    int oddCounter = myDictionary.Count -evenCounter;
```

Comment: Alright, I did the same too but was told you shouldn't use a dictionary when it comes to iterating. oh well..

Comment: This is exactly what the OP said they thought about doing but are asking about a different approach.

Comment: We don't need keys for identifying the number of odds, so you can simply use arrays to store, and just iterate over the arrays, if you like it.