# Converting Enumeration<Integer> for loop from Java to C#? What exactly is an Enumeration<Integer> in C#?

Tags: java, c#

I'm converting a project from Java to C#. I've tried to search this, but all I come across is questions about enums. There is a Hashtable htPlaylist, and the loop uses Enumeration to go through the keys. How would I convert this code to C#, but using a Dictionary instead of a Hashtable?

```
// My C# Dictionary, formerly a Java Hashtable.
Dictionary<int, SongInfo> htPlaylist = MySongs.getSongs();

// Original Java code trying to convert to C# using a Dictionary.
for(Enumeration<Integer> e = htPlaylist.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();
{
    // What would nextElement() be in a Dictonary? 
    SongInfo popularSongs = htPlaylist.get(e.nextElement());
}
```

Comment: Yikes, how old is this Java code?

Comment: [What is the best way to iterate over a Dictionary in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c)

Comment: So I should just do foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string>? What exactly is an Enumeration<Integer> in Java though? What would be the equivalence of that in C#?

Comment: Disregard, got my answer in another thread about hashtables on stackoverflow. It is a duplicate, please allow me to delete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eh, just a `foreach` loop? For the given

```
   Dictionary<int, SongInfo> htPlaylist = MySongs.getSongs();
```

either

```
   foreach (var pair in htPlaylist) {
     // int key = pair.Key;
     // SongInfo info = pair.Value;
     ...
   }
```

or if you want just keys:

```
   foreach (int key in htPlaylist.Keys) {
     ...
   }
```