# How to iterate through keys and values of an `IDictionary`?

Tags: c#, idictionary

How would I iterate through the keys and values of an `IDictionary` if I don't know the concrete types of the keys and values within, therefore want to just treat them as `object`s?

If I do something like:

`foreach(var x in myIDictionary) { ... }`

I think `x` is an `object`. But how would I get the `Key` and `Value` out of it (both typed as `object`s), as specified in the `IDictionaryEnumerator`? There isn't an `IKeyValuePair` without generic parameters is there?

I guess I could loop through the enumerator by hand using `MoveNext` etc, but I feel like there must be a way to do it with `foreach`!

Comment: `I think x is an object` Why don't you check what it actually is, rather than just guessing.

Comment: @Servy x IS an object, everything is an object in OOP

Comment: @BernardWalters Servy is well aware of that. His point is that OP hasn't bothered to check what `x` is before coming here to ask us.

Comment: @BernardWalters It's a type that's derived from an object.  It's convertible to "object".  The type of `x` is not "object" though.

Comment: The reason I'm not sure is that I don't know for sure where I would find out. Obviously I can find out the concrete type in the debugger, but I don't know what the type is supposed to be? I *think* it's the type of `IDictionaryEnumerator.Current`, but is that correct? (I did bother to try - otherwise I wouldn't be on StackOverflow in the first place.)

Comment: @JosephHumfrey You can look at the documentation for the type if you want to find out what the items are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to iterate over a Dictionary in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c)

Comment: _everything is an object in OOP_ A common misconception. C# is a language that carfully follows oop rules most but not all the time. Everything ís an object in other oop languages, like Smalltallk.

Comment: @Servy - see the answers - it's not entirely straightforward (e.g. "there isn't a clear type" v.s. "you can use `DictionaryEntry`, but not always"). But feel free to point me in the direction of a documentation that clearly gives a definitive answer.

Comment: @JosephHumfrey I'm entirely confident in your ability to find the documentation for `IDictionary` on your own.  You don't need me (or other answerers) to find it for you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can explicitly specify `DictionaryEntry` pair type in `foreach` like this:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry x in myIDictionary)
```

Though you should be sure that it is standard implementation of `IDictionary` (like `Hashtable` or `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`)

Otherwise it can be literally anything in enumerator.

Comment: Perhaps this is a nitpick, but there isn't any requirement that `IDictionaryEnumerator.Current` be a `DictionaryEntry` and that is what `foreach` uses. It would be pretty weird if it weren't, but not a violation of the interface.

Comment: I guess my point of confusion is the fact that an `IDictionary`'s enumerator uses `DictionaryEntry`, and yet a concrete `Dictionary<string, int>` (for example), would use a `KeyValuePair<string, int>` (which isn't related to a `DictionaryEntry`). So the behaviour actually depends on the specific casting of the dictionary variable that you iterate.

Comment: @JLRishe yes, indeed

Comment: @JosephHumfrey that confusion understandable. That is working because of explicit implementations of `GetEnumerator.` If you are not casting to `IDictionary` - then you will not be able to use `DictionaryEntry` in `foreach`

Comment: @JosephHumfrey - That does not matter. It still works and a generic `Dictionary<T,U>` still implements `IDictionary` and because it does you can still use `DictionaryEntry` as the implementation is interface explicitly. See [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vcRPPw).

Comment: @Igor Nobody is denying that that will work on a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, but there is nothing in the `IDictionary` interface to ensure that the iterator variable will be a `DictionaryEntry` (see my comment above).

Comment: @JLRishe - your right, I thought you were the OP (joseph), my fault.

Comment: @Igor No worries :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer and the insightful comments!

Answer (score 8):

The point you're missing is that there are no guarantees of what the type of the values will be if you iterate an `IDictionary`. They could be literally anything. The only guarantee is that it implements `.GetEnumerator()`.

If you want to iterate over the contents of the `IDictionary`, you can iterate over its keys:

```
foreach (object key in myIDictionary.Keys)
{
    object value = myIDictionary[key];

    // do something with key and value
}
```

You can also convert your `IDictionary` to a `Dictionary<object, object>` to make `foreach` a bit more friendly:

```
var myDictionary = myIDictionary.Keys
                                .Cast<object>()
                                .ToDictionary(k => k, k => d[k]);

// kv is a KeyValuePair<object, object>
foreach (var kv in dobj)
{

}
```

You can even add an extension method to do this for you:

```
public static Dictionary<object, object> ToDictionary(this IDictionary dict)
{
    return dict.Keys.Cast<object>().ToDictionary(k => k, k => dict[k]);
}


// usage
// kv is a KeyValuePair<object, object>
foreach (var kv in myIDictionary.ToDictionary())
{
}
```