# How to print contents of a list via a dictionary?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, foreach

I have a list declared such as:

```
string[] myList = { "Item One", "Item Two", "Item Three" };
```

And a dictionary with one element, which value points towards above list:

```
Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
myDictionary.Add("DictionaryItem", myList);
```

I would like to print the contents of `myList` by pointing to the value in the dictionary. I have tried:

```
foreach (string element in myDictionary["DictionaryItem"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Returns syntax error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type object because object does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator.

How can I print `myList`, by pointing to the value of `"DictionaryItem"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to iterate over a Dictionary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c)

Comment: Cast myDictionary["DictionaryItem"] to an array or what ever you need.

Comment: Unless there is strict requirement, ideally try using strongly typed objects where ever possible, ex: `Dictionary<string, string[]>` or `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>` etc., in your case, to reduce unnecessary & costly Casts and you can get intellisense support as a bonus while in supported IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A foreach statement can only be used over an object inheriting `IEnumerable`. As the `TValue` of your dictionary is `object`, your foreach statement cannot compile even if it is actually an `IEnumerable` under the hood.

You have several choices to solve that issue:

**Change your TValue**

Best option, only if you can of course:

```
var myDictionary  = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

Notice the keywork `var` in the variable definition. You can save a lot of time when instantiating objects like this.

**Cast the result of `myDictionary["DictionaryItem"]` into an `IEnumerable`**

Dangerous option if there is other types of object in your dictionary.

```
foreach (string element in (myDictionary["DictionaryItem"] as string[]))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

*Remark:* I am talking about `IEnumerable` and I use `string[]` in my options. That's because the C# array (`[]`) inherits from `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are referring to a `string[]` as an object in this example - are you looking to use `object[]` for the array?
Either way the error is pretty explicit. 
You will need to use `Dictionary<string, string[]> myDictionary`

Answer (score 1):

It is just an object so foreach is not going to know how process it

```
string[] myList = (string[])myDictionary["DictionaryItem"];

foreach(string s in myList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a List of string from the String[] and iterate on that. Note that you want to iterate on the value of the dictionary item.

```
        string[] myList = { "Item One", "Item Two", "Item Three" };
        Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        myDictionary.Add("DictionaryItem", myList);


        //Short Hand
        foreach (var item in new List<string>((string[])myDictionary.First(m => m.Key == "DictionaryItem").Value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        //or Long Hand version
        KeyValuePair<string, object> element = myDictionary.First(m => m.Key == "DictionaryItem");
        List<String> listItem = new List<string>((string[])element.Value);
        foreach (var item in listItem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```