# Dynamically Deserialize JSON to C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization

I have a JSON file I'm trying to deserialize to a list with a dictionary as the values, but struggling with getting the output in a nice format and struggling to index/parse it once it's deserialized.  I'm new to this and would appreciate the help.  I would like the key/value pairs to look like: {"greeting" : ["greet1": "hey", "greet2" : "hi"]}

JSON file below:

```
{
"greeting": [
        {
          "greet1": "hey",
          "greet2": "hi"
        }
      ],
"bye": [
        {
          "bye1": "adios"
        }
      ]
}
```

Attempted code:

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> jsonResponses = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>();

public static void DeserializeJsonDict()
{
    string jsonURL = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("./theFile.json");

    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var jsonData = webClient.DownloadString(jsonURL);
        jsonResponses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>>(jsonData);

    }

}
```

Comment: do you want to to dynamically generate a class object as the input jsonstring? like : `Object{objGreeting{propGreeting1,propGreeting2},objBye{propBye1}}`?

Comment: What is your problem?  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>>(jsonData)` works perfectly.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/V3NX3n for a demo.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I’m now struggling to index the output to pull out the values. How would I index the dictionary and the list within the dictionary?

Comment: Are you looking for [What is the best way to iterate over a Dictionary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/141088)?

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(str), new Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>());

Comment: @AvaniReddy so the question is actually how to use the converted object? Maybe try JObject.Parse or JArray.Parse methods, that are made for such purposes

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = @"{'greeting':[{'greet1': 'hey','greet2': 'hi'}],'bye': [{'bye1': 'adios'}]}";    
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(str, new Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>());
```

You can refer properties directly e.g. `data.greeting`. Also, there is one more approach to traverse convertion results - using `KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>` as  generic type parameter gives you ability to iterate over dynamic values, e.g.

```
foreach (var i in data){
  Console.WriteLine(i.Key);
  foreach(var v in i.Value) Console.WriteLine(v); 
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/UUvMeA

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current json format is that "greeting" and "bye" will be used as keys in deserialization. This prevents your objects from being deserialized into a list or an array.

If the JSON is created by manually editing the file, then if it is changed to

```
[
  {
    "greeting": {
      "greet1": "hey",
      "greet2": "hi"
    }
  },
  {
    "bye": {
      "bye1": "adios"
    }
  }
]
```

...it can be deserialized as follows:

```
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>>(jsonInputData);
```

See Also: [C# - Deserialize array of JSON objects into Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77165172/19497610)

Answer (score -1):

```
string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";

var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```