# How to print the Dictionary Key and multiples values for that key in the same line in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, dependencies, client

I have the client below for a Web Api application, inside this client I have a dictionary with multiple dependencies. I would like to print to the log file the a line with the key and multiple values. as the dictionary is in a separeted class I can not reach the values correctly. 
This is the input:

```
 [{
    "Inputs": [{
        "Input": "A B C"
    }, {
        "Input": "B C E "
    }, {
        "Input": "C G"
    }, {
        "Input": "D A  F"
    }, {
        "Input": "E F"
    }, {
        "Input": "F H "
    }]
}]
```

this is my DataReader class where the dictionary is:

```
public class DataReader
    {
        public Dictionary<char, char[]> Read()
        {
            JArray data;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:input.json"))
            {
                data = (JArray)JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(sr));
            }

            var values = data.SelectTokens("..Input").Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
            var dict = values.ToDictionary(s => s[0], v => v.Substring(2).Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());

            IEnumerable<char> Dependencies(char input)
            {
                yield return input;
                if (dict.TryGetValue(input, out char[] childDepends))
                {
                    foreach (char result in childDepends.SelectMany(Dependencies))
                    {
                        yield return result;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (char s in values.Select(x => x[0]))
            {
                Console.Write(s); Console.Write(" ");
                //the line below calls the IEnumerable Dependencies:

                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", dict[s].SelectMany(Dependencies).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x)));
            }
            return dict;
```

this is my program.cs class where I need to call the dictionary and print the values:

```
class Program : ApiController
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    DataReader reader;
    public Program()
    {
        reader = new DataReader();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        DataReader reader = new DataReader();
        var data = reader.Read();
        foreach (var key in data.Keys)
        {
            foreach (var s in data.Values)
            {
                //assembly of values to send
                var transactionId = Guid.NewGuid();
                string userName = "test";
               string message = string.Join(" ", "<< Dependencies for", key, ">>",s[0]);                 
                 // write the file here 
                var logLine = string.Join(",", transactionId, message);

                using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"C:\log.txt"))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(logLine);
                }
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56047/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var payload = new ProcessorDto();
                payload.UserName = userName;
                payload.Message = message;
                var result = await client.PostAsync("api/validate", payload, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
                var responseData = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // update log with response:
                var fileText = File.ReadAllText(@"log.txt");
                var updatedLine = logLine + "," + responseData;
                fileText = fileText.Replace(logLine, updatedLine);
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\log.txt", fileText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the code above prints the below to the console:

```
A   B C E F G H
B   C E F G H
C   G
D   A B C E F G H
E   F H
F   H
```

this part of my code needs to be modified as it is writing the log.txt incorrectly:

```
string message = string.Join(" ", "<< Dependencies for", key, ">>",s[0]);
```

I am not sure what to add on the s[0] as it is returning the below:

> 23b3c058-8ec0-4925-9e42-ae5de2863ca7,<< Dependencies for A >>
>   B,"False"
>
> c5f778d8-6eac-4508-b01f-864f4a49f57a,<< Dependencies for A >>
>   C,"False"
>
> 8d5821b3-2f68-40fd-a18c-473d6aa222ad,<< Dependencies for A >>
>   G,"False"
>
> 8e693ea8-e97b-4e6a-831b-c0348d918e29,<< Dependencies for A >>
>   A,"False"
>
> af7a4497-8c18-401b-b287-b05abb94f5e8,<< Dependencies for A >>
>   F,"False"
>
> ecad1901-c503-488a-a5f2-6ec04d5ac7a9,<< Dependencies for A >>
>   H,"False"
>   50d4edb9-770b-4c6d-be54-9f738cde6dd1, << Dependencies forB>>C,"False"
>
> 208c8ae4-e669-4f06-8548-c1035c22ff61, << Dependencies forB>>G,"False"
>
> e001b386-02c0-4111-a715-c4d524074be4, << Dependencies forB>>A,"False"
>
> 19fbe253-284b-4221-a762-e2eedb9b2d73, << Dependencies forB>>F,"False"
>
> e100ce7f-be94-4fc5-a592-f4088a031b6d, << Dependencies forB>>H,"False"
>
> e645a38c-a33d-428d-90be-d6f34d27c935, << Dependencies forC>>B,"False"
>
> 07031b1a-8546-4f9e-8f49-78a6d8ef1bfa, << Dependencies forC>>C,"False"
>
> 3d9de182-9c32-4716-bff9-0840c176cec6, << Dependencies forC>>G,"False"
>
> 623c4529-b025-4e4d-abb3-98ea21e40381, << Dependencies forC>>A,"False"
>
> ee46a0ae-2518-4848-9d87-9fb554d527de, << Dependencies forC>>F,"False"
>
> a0769061-2c72-44cd-a174-ee11766bb920, << Dependencies forC>>H,"False"
>
> 311be8b8-93fe-420d-b0ae-6b74af3291e2, << Dependencies forD>>B,"False"
>
> f7304991-51fc-42b1-bd31-749c6fde77d3, << Dependencies forD>>C,"False"
>
> c59163c8-d4bb-4720-845c-2e1111d2cde5, << Dependencies forD>>G,"False"
>
> cd7869bf-5427-470e-a064-6bc785867eb3, << Dependencies forD>>A,"False"
>
> 7f96e0cf-764e-4803-a70a-b28e8da8f85e, << Dependencies forD>>F,"False"
>
> 65c5ac2f-22eb-4e84-9b8d-35c1e0e4d862, << Dependencies forD>>H,"False"
>
> 0ffeaad0-1626-43b3-9e45-050d62023e69, << Dependencies forE>>B,"False"
>
> 3a7e2625-4e27-4f33-af11-c75fb7568560, << Dependencies forE>>C,"False"
>
> cb9f2d26-bd62-4200-a7aa-74190d124389, << Dependencies forE>>G,"False"
>
> 6e063ec1-c82d-4a84-85f1-2f8baba281c6, << Dependencies forE>>A,"False"
>
> 63895dc3-de7b-42f6-b0e3-fdc429ae5fc3, << Dependencies forE>>F,"False"
>
> a1626f22-b476-4d00-a08c-aab08b07e5ef, << Dependencies forE>>H,"False"
>
> faa2dc3c-3303-46d0-8f68-2ac1272504d1, << Dependencies forF>>B,"False"
>
> 031e5115-30ed-4ada-9db2-729df8dd7897, << Dependencies forF>>C,"False"
>
> 90577a7a-cc12-4a57-a9de-97b93b59398f, << Dependencies forF>>G,"False"
>
> 2b668cb0-5d6a-4b7c-8326-c8cf39436bbf, << Dependencies forF>>A,"False"
>
> c15b1c49-534f-40e6-8f10-c16cd66a6cb2, << Dependencies forF>>F,"False"
>
> 4aabfcc0-dfc7-45a2-b346-e7fade4f48ff, << Dependencies forF>>H,"False"
>
> but it should be  as below:
>
> 23b3c058-8ec0-4925-9e42-ae5de2863ca7,<< Dependencies for A >> B, C, E,
>   F, G, H,"False"
>   23b3c058-8ec0-4925-9e42-ae5de2863ca7,<< Dependencies for B >> C, E, F, G, H "False"
>   23b3c058-8ec0-4925-9e42-ae5de2863ca7,<< Dependencies for C >> G "False"
>   23b3c058-8ec0-4925-9e42-ae5de2863ca7,<< Dependencies for D >> A, B, C, E,  F, G, H "False"
>   23b3c058-8ec0-4925-9e42-ae5de2863ca7,<< Dependencies for E >> F, H "False"
>   23b3c058-8ec0-4925-9e42-ae5de2863ca7,<< Dependencies for F >> H "False"

What should I add to the code below to print the correct output

**string message = string.Join(" ", "<< Dependencies for", key, ">>",s[0]);**

Comment: string message = string.Join(",", s[0].Select(x => x.Key + ":" x.Value));

Comment: @jdweng thank you but I cannot access the key and value using your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested foreach loops are not necessary.  [Iterating a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary) gives you a [KeyValuePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.7.2).  Try using that to access the key and the value (in your case, the 'char' and 'char[]'), like so:

```
        foreach (var kvp in data)
        {
            //assembly of values to send
            var transactionId = Guid.NewGuid();
            var userName = "test";

            var message = $"{transactionId},<< Dependencies for {kvp.Key}>>" + string.Join(",", kvp.Value);

            // your other stuff here
        }
```

EDIT:
Ok, so here's a working console application demonstrating a recursive solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
   internal class Program
   {
      #region Static Fields and Constants

      private static readonly string json =
         "[" +
         "{\"Inputs\": [" +
         "{\"Input\": \"A B C\"}," +
         "{\"Input\": \"B C E \"}," +
         "{\"Input\": \"C G\"}," +
         "{\"Input\": \"D A  F\"}," +
         "{\"Input\": \"E F\"}," +
         "{\"Input\": \"F H \"}" +
         "]}" +
         "]";

      #endregion

      #region Public Methods

      public static void GetDependencies(char key, Dictionary<char, char[]> inputs, ref List<char> totalDependencies)
      {
         // stopping cases (the stack will unwind when all dependencies have been explored)
         if (!inputs.ContainsKey(key) || inputs[key] == null || inputs[key].Length == 0) {
            return;
         }

         var deps = inputs[key];
         foreach (var dep in deps) {
            // we've already added this branch of the dependency tree so go to the next dependency
            if (totalDependencies.Contains(dep)) {
               continue;
            }

            // the recursion (see how this method calls itself?)
            GetDependencies(dep, inputs, ref totalDependencies);
            totalDependencies.Add(dep);
         }
      }

      public static string BuildDependencies(Dictionary<char, char[]> inputs)
      {
         var sb = new StringBuilder();
         foreach (var input in inputs) {
            var td = new List<char>();
            GetDependencies(input.Key, inputs, ref td);
            sb.AppendLine($"{Guid.NewGuid()}, << Dependencies for {input.Key} >> {string.Join(",", td)},\"False\"");
         }

         return sb.ToString();
      }

      #endregion

      private static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var data = JArray.Parse(json);
         var values = data.SelectTokens("..Input").Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
         var inputs = MakeInputs(values);

         Console.WriteLine(BuildDependencies(inputs));
      }

      private static Dictionary<char, char[]> MakeInputs(IEnumerable<string> values)
      {
         var dict = new Dictionary<char, char[]>();
         foreach (var s in values) {
            var parts = s.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray();
            var deps = parts.Skip(1).Take(parts.Length).ToArray();
            var key = parts[0];

            dict[key] = deps;
         }

         return dict;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @3166332 thank you for the answer, but it is printing only :  `93c5ea3e-6110-4ed3-af3d-b11792ab4bb9,93c5ea3e-6110-4ed3-af3d-b11792ab4bb9,<< Dependencies for A>>B,C,"False"` it should print the below: `93c5ea3e-6110-4ed3-af3d-b11792ab4bb9,93c5ea3e-6110-4ed3-af3d-b11792ab4bb9,<< Dependencies for A>>B,C, E, F, G, H "False"`

Comment: @user7390660 Sorry, my bad. I didn't quite understand the input and desired output.  What you want is: for 'A' (for example) should be the dependencies of 'A' ('B' & 'C') + the dependencies of 'B' ('C' & 'E') + the dependencies of 'C' ('G') + the dependencies of 'E' ('F') + the dependencies of 'G'.  That screams: [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).  I'll edit my answer.