# C# print dictionary content

Tags: c#

How can I print the content of my dictionary and check when IDs are same.
Like for example I get an Id like B83773, if it's appear in the dictionary I would print it on console.

Any kind of help will be super appreciated, I do not really understand the concept.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
        string ExtractIDFromFileName(string filename)
        {
            return filename.Split('_').Last();
        }

        Dictionary<string, int> GetDictOfIDCounts()
        {
            List<string> allfiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:/filet/", "*.wish").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList();
            allfiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("C:/filet/", "*.exe").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList());
            Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach (var x in allfiles)
            {
                string fileID = ExtractIDFromFileName(x);

                if (dict.ContainsKey(fileID))
                {
                    dict[fileID]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    dict.Add(fileID, 1);
                }
            }

            return dict;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("" );
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. You already have `if (dict.ContainsKey(fileID))`, what other than this is it that you require? Are you just missing a `Console.WriteLine` statement inside the `{ ... }` for that if-statement, is that it?

Comment: Well I want to count whenever an ID appear more than 1 time and print them with a console.writeline, but I don't know how to call the Dictionnary

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's a **dictionary** - one "n" is **QUITE** enough !

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, what exactly do you mean by "call the dictionary"? `dict.ContainsKey(fileID)` checks if the key already exists in the dictionary, and returns `true` if it does, `false` if it doesn't.

Comment: are you looking for this: `Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", fileID,dict[fileID] );` But I don't get why these up-votes for an unclear question

Comment: I actually don't understand how to print all the IDs on Console

Comment: Print all the ids? Or all the ids that you increase for? It seems you've mashed two different criteria into one question, "print the content of your dictionary" and "check when IDs are the same". You already do the latter part.

Comment: What do you want to achieve when the IDs are the same? Avoid writing it to the console again? Othen than that your ' dict[fileID]++;' seems unnecessary, just replace it with Console.WriteLine(dict[fileID])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to iterate over a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question, you can call your method `GetDictOfIDCounts()` and iterate thru it:

```
var result = GetDictOfIDCounts();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} > {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Key would be the string of your file ID and Value the count.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<string> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "a"};

        var myDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var letter in list)
        {
            if (!myDict.ContainsKey(letter))
            {
                myDict.Add(letter, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                myDict[letter]++;
            }
        }

        foreach (var letter in myDict.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{letter} : {myDict[letter]}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```