# How to access Dictionary Model Property value from View - ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get value of Dictionary from View.
In the view, I have a main/first **foreach loop** that retrieve data from Model, and inside the **main/first loop**, I need to retrieve the **ListAttribute** value according to the first loop by Id.

```
**//Code in the View - First loop to retrieve data from Model**
@model IEnumerable<ABC.Web.Models.Room.Housing>
foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.Id))
{
    <div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">

    *...(remainer of the code)*

    //Here to insert second loop to retrieve *ListAttribute*
}


//Code in the Model 
namespace ABC.Web.Models.Room
{    
    public class Housing
    {
        public string[] FloorPlan { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, ListAttribute> ListAttributes { get; set;}
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ListAttribute
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't understand what type has `Model` and from where do you get `Id` property

Comment: I edited the above and added Model's Type

Answer (score 0):

If `item` is an object of type `Housing`, then you can do this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ListAttribute> listItem in item.ListAttributes)
{
    // Then you will have...
    // listItem.Key -> string
    // listItem.Value -> ListAttribute
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/141088/1267304)

Comment: It doesn't work me. It's displaying the key value for all the **Id** from the top **foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.Id))**   I want to display dictionary value per Id.

Comment: @Chloe must be something wrong with your Model then.. if an `item` is a different iteration from your Model, and then you display data for that `item`, it should be also different.