# Serialize object from a string?

Tags: c#

I have a class like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerInfo
{
  public string playerId;
  public string deviceId;

  public static PlayerInfo CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
  {
    return JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(jsonString);
  }
}
```

And my client receives updates with a function like this:

```
void OnPlayerLocalJoin(Socket socket, Packet packet, params object[] args)
{
  Debug.Log(args[0]);
}
```

According to [the documentation](https://besthttp-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#3.%20Socket.IO/2%20Subscribing%20and%20receiving%20events/) (which need more detail), the `args` should use the default json decoder, but I see it returns `args` as `System.Object[]`, but oddly enough when I try `args[0]` my log returns:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

When I print out the raw "packet" object, I do see my object:

```
[ "playerLocalUpdate", {"playerId":"abc","deviceId":"150B"} ]
```

No matter what I try, I cannot get the second part of this array to be a dictionary or better yet, how can I get it to be an instance of `PlayerInfo`

```
Debug.Log(packet.ToString());
var serialized = JsonUtility.ToJson(packet.ToString());
Debug.Log(serialized);
```

I'm trying to follow the docs: https://besthttp-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#3.%20Socket.IO/2%20Subscribing%20and%20receiving%20events/

Comment: You haven’t posted your deserialization code.

Comment: Don't try to serialize the string, instead serialize the object...

Comment: Its just one big string, the packet is a stringified array with two items in it the second one being the one i want as json.

Comment: I think you need to deserialize it then serialize only "second one"

Comment: Maybe im not explaining this correctly, all i have is a string which looks like this: "[ "playerLocalUpdate", {"playerId":"abc","deviceId":"150B"} ]" how can I get the second item in the array, and make it a JSON object?

Comment: There is no such thing as JSON object in `c#`. Please explain also a use case.

Comment: I tried to add more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy bit is you want to do

```
PlayerInfo newPlayerInfo = PlayerInfo.CreateFromJSON(jsonString);
```

where jsonString is '{"playerId":"abc","deviceId":"150B"}'.  We can see that from the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html).  I think you've worked that out already.

As you say, you can see this string arriving in your packet.  As you also say, it's not clear from the HTTP/2 docs what args contains.  Although the dictionary may be the string we want converted to a dictionary, which isn't much use to us. You could investigate further by casting args[0] to Dictionary<string, object> and then [doing a foreach on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary) and logging the results.  I'm also unclear what args[1] might contain?

Maybe it is best to get it out of the packet.  My guess is that to get the jsonString you need to do something like:

```
var packetArray = JsonUtility.FromJson<object[]>(packet.ToString());
string jsonString = packetArray[1].ToString();
```

That's because packet is JSON and we want to convert FROM the JSON string (which represents an array) to a C# array.  Then we want the second item in the array.  I think.  It's hard to be sure without access to the code.

Comment: Rich, thank you, you read into my issue and understood my problem in a way I could not explain.