# What to use for covariance over fn parameter in Rust?

Tags: c#, rust, covariance

today I have learned that rust does not support covariance over an fn parameter only its return type is covariant. ([see rust doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html))

Why did I learn about that fact in rust? Because I tried to implement a very simple game where I have separated the logic, the event handling, and the drawing in three distinct functions but all operating on the same vector of players.

**If this is not possible what would be the equivalent in rust compared to the c# version be?**

In C# this is quite simple [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rPjzvK)
You can define an interface Y that a class X has to implement and define a corresponding delegate which requires as a parameter an IEnumerable of that Interface Y. Now you can share a List of X between different methods that require only an interface Y.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public interface Actionable{
    void Do();
}

public interface Drawable{
    void Draw();
}

public class Player: Drawable, Actionable{

    public void Do(){
        Console.WriteLine("Action");
    }

    public void Draw(){
        Console.WriteLine("Draw");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public delegate void DrawHandler(IEnumerable<Drawable> obj);
    public delegate void LogicHandler(IEnumerable<Actionable> obj);

    public static void gameloop(DrawHandler draw,LogicHandler action){

        List<Player> list = new List<Player>(){
            new Player()
        };

        for(int rounds = 0; rounds < 500; rounds++){
            draw(list);
            action(list);
        }

    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        gameloop(
             list =>{
                foreach(var item in list){
                    item.Draw();
                }
            },
            list =>{
                foreach(var item in list){
                    item.Do();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Naive as I am, I tried to do something equivalent to that in rust!

```rust
trait Drawable {
    fn draw(&self) {
        println!("draw object");
    }
}

trait Actionable {
    fn do_action(&self, action: &String) {
        println!("Do {}", action);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Position {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
}
impl Position {
    fn new(x: u32, y: u32) -> Position {
        Position { x, y }
    }
}
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Player {
    pos: Position,
    name: String,
}

impl Player {
    fn new(name: String) -> Player {
        Player {
            name,
            pos: Position::new(0, 0),
        }
    }
}

impl Drawable for Player {
    fn draw(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self);
    }
}

impl Actionable for Player {
    fn do_action(&self, action: &String) {
        println!("Do {} {}!", action, self.name);
    }
}

type DrawHandler = fn(drawables: &Vec<&dyn Drawable>) -> Result<(), String>;
type LogicHandler = fn(actions: &Vec<&dyn Actionable>) -> Result<(), String>;
type EventHandler = fn(events: &mut sdl2::EventPump) -> Result<bool, String>;

fn game_loop(
    window: &mut windowContext,
    draw_handler: DrawHandler,
    event_handler: EventHandler,
    logic_handler: LogicHandler,
) -> Result<(), String> {
    let mut objects: Vec<&Player> = Vec::new();

    objects.push(&Player::new("b".to_string()));

    while event_handler(&mut window.events)? {
        logic_handler(&objects)?; // Does Not work

        window.canvas.clear();

        draw_handler(&objects)?; // Does Not Work
        window.canvas.present();
        ::std::thread::sleep(Duration::new(0, 1_000_000_000u32 / 60));
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

**If this is not possible what would be the equivalent in rust compared to the c# version be?**

I accept that this is not possible in rust. I would like to know what instead is used in rust

Comment: You could look at https://github.com/amethyst/amethyst, but this question is far too broad for a SO question, and I will not call your code "simple", on the contrary, I would advice you to keep it simple, don't try to do so much abstraction before you need it.

Comment: @Stargateur thanks for the link. Are you sure its too broad for SO, because if i see questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary?rq=1

I assumed this one would fit.

Comment: I don't see the link between a basic question such at iterating on a collection, and your question that would require a book to answer. You just pick a random C# question.

Comment: Indeed I did. I think I lack the skill to see the ramification of my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rust, very few things are done implicitly, which includes casting as you discovered.

In this case, casting a `Vec<&T>` into a `Vec<&dyn Trait>` would be impossible (Given that `T != dyn Trait`), because of how trait objects are stored; they're two pointer-widths wide while normal references are one pointer-width wide. This means the length of the `Vec`, in bytes would need to be doubled.

> I accept that this is not possible in rust. I would like to know what instead is used in rust

If you're only using one kind of object, you can just restrict the type:

```
type DrawHandler = fn(drawables: &Vec<Player>) -> Result<(), String>;
type LogicHandler = fn(actions: &Vec<Player>) -> Result<(), String>;
```

However, there most likely won't only be players in your game, and instead you'd like to include other aspects.

This can be done a few ways:

- Using `enum`s to represent each type of object. Then your function inputs can take values of the type of the `enum`:

```rust
enum GamePiece {
    Player(Player),
    Enemy(Enemy),
    Item(Item),
    //etc.
}
```

- Using an ECS which can manage arbitrary objects based on what properties they have. Some ECSs that exist in rust are:

  - [`legion`](https://github.com/TomGillen/legion)
  - [`specs`](https://github.com/amethyst/specs)
  - [`ecs`](https://docs.rs/ecs/0.23.1/ecs/)
  - [`shipyard`](https://github.com/leudz/shipyard)
  - And a few more

  In general, their usage will look something like this:

```rust
struct DrawingComponent {
    buffers: Buffer
}
struct DirectionAI {
    direction: Vector
}
struct Position {
    position: Point
}

let mut world = World::new();
world.insert((DrawingComponent::new(), DirectionAI::new(), Position::new()));

for (pos, direction) in world.iter_over(<(&mut Position, &DirectionAI)>::query()) {
    pos.position += direction.direction;
}
for (pos, drawable) in world.iter_over(<&Position, &mut DrawingComponent>::query()) {
    drawable.buffers.set_position(*pos);
    draw(drawable);
}
```

In this system, you work generically over components, and not over types. This way, the ECS can store and access items very quickly, and efficiently.

---

Covariance in Rust *does* exist. It just isn't OOP covariance, it's covariance over lifetimes. [The Rust Nomicon covers it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance), since it's a bit of a niche thing for day-to-day users.

Note that the table in that section covers variance of `'a`, `T`, and in some cases, `U`. In the case of `T`, and `U`, the variance there, is in any lifetime parameters they may have, and not of the type itself. IE, it describes how `'b` is variant (or invariant) in `Struct<'b>`, and not how `Struct<'b>` can be cast to `dyn Trait + 'b`.

Answer (score 1):

Treating a `&Player` as `&dyn Drawable` looks like using a subtype in a super type but actually it is a type conversion (both look completely different in memory @Optimistic Peach explained it in more detail).

With this in mind a `Vec<Player>` cannot be casted into a `Vec<&dyn Drawable>`, it has to be converted. Your code with an explicit conversion would look like this:

```
fn game_loop(
    draw_handler: DrawHandler,
    logic_handler: LogicHandler,
) -> Result<(), String> {
    let mut objects: Vec<Player> = Vec::new();

    objects.push(Player::new("b".to_string()));

    for i in 0..1 {
        let actionable = objects.iter().map(|v| v as &dyn Actionable).collect();
        logic_handler(&actionable)?; // Does work!

        let drawables = objects.iter().map(|v| v as &dyn Drawable).collect();
        draw_handler(&drawables)?; // Does work!
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

This should only demonstrate the consequences of converting `&Player` to `&dyn Drawable` - it is not the best way how to solve your problem.