# Can i check if a double value is between pair values inside a Dictionary<double,double>

Tags: c#

I have the following:-

```
double v = 1.1;
Dictionary<double,double> cleanedTimes = new Dictionary<double,double>();
//code for building the cleanedTimes goes here..
```

so how i can check if the `v` is between any the pair values inside the `cleanedTimes` items?

Thanka

Comment: @Steve i meant to say double

Comment: define "pair values" please.

Comment: Please provide an example of how your dictionary is initialized and an example of the positive result as well one of the negative result expected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to iterate over a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary)

Comment: From the question wording I would say something like  `v >= cleanedTimes.Values.Min() && v <= cleanedTimes.Values.Max()`

Comment: It appears your using a dictionary just because it returns to you a KeyValuePair.  It doesn't appear you will be using the Key for anything, you should really consider just using a better data-structure such as an IEnumerable<(double, double)> or some other abstraction

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Any()` with any condition you like. Your condition would be as simple as "bigger than the key, but smaller than the value or the other way round". So the expression/code can look like this:

```
IDictionary<double, double> values = new Dictionary<double, double>();
values.Add(1.1, 2.2);
values.Add(3.3, 4.4);
values.Add(5.5, 5.0);

double check = 1.5;

bool found = values.Any(it => (it.Key <= check && check <= it.Value) ||
                              (it.Value <= check && check <= it.Key));
Console.WriteLine(found);
```

This will print `True` as the value `check` of `1.5` is between `1.1` and `2.2`.

Comment: I thinnk it should be `Any(it => check >= it.Key && check <= it.Value);` if i translate the requirement _"between any the pair values"_ correctly, because i think "pair values" means that he stores the pair in the key and in the value.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's what I wrote? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Can you check https://dotnetfiddle.net/pTPBos, am I missing something? I don't get what you are saying.

Comment: Your first condition is correct, i got it wrong first time. But why you need the second?

Comment: @TimSchmelter The `key` might be bigger than the `value` as seen in the 3rd example KeyValuePair, but the value to search for might still be between these numbers.

Comment: ok, but op didnt mention this. I think that this would be a bug. If you have a collection with two properties where the first stores the min- and the second stores the max-value, i would not handle the case that somehow wrong values were stored in each property. At least not where i evaluate the collection but where i fill it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter OP didn't mention that the `key` is always smaller than the `value` either. The conditions makes sure that both "directions" are checked.